# How to find the size of integer array

Tags: c, arrays

How to find the size of an integer array in C.

Any method available without traversing the whole array once, to find out the size of the array.

Comment: How did you implement this array? In principle either you know the array size in O(1) (known size), O(N) (nil-terminated), or impossible.

Comment: Usually arrays are created as static variable and you must have passed some length while creating it.

Comment: @Jack: Why would arrays "usually" be static???

Comment: int len = strlen(array); ???

Comment: *"Any method available without traversing the whole array once, to find out the size of the array."* - I would rather like know how you would traverse the array *without* knowing its size beforehand?

Comment: Possible duplicates (there are alot of these)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16101836/size-of-a-dynamically-allocated-integer-array?lq=1
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975128/sizeof-an-array-in-the-c-programming-language
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493281/c-sizeof-a-passed-array
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545428/size-of-array-in-c

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I determine the size of my array in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-my-array-in-c)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

If the array is a global, static, or automatic variable (`int array[10];`), then `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])` works.

If it is a dynamically allocated array (`int* array = malloc(sizeof(int)*10);`) or passed as a function argument (`void f(int array[])`), then you cannot find its size at run-time. You will have to store the size somewhere.
Note that `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])` compiles just fine even for the second case, but it will silently produce the wrong result.

Comment: Perhaps mention and point to a question explaining array decay? Frequent topic

Comment: For the C++ novices arriving at this C question: [Everything you ever wanted to know about arrays in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4810664/140719) in one FAQ.

Comment: Are the parentheses around sizeof necessary?

Comment: @lololololol In principle, you can use **`sizeof`** without the parentheses. Except in some circumstances. I never even tried to read the fineprint, and instead subscribed to the common practice to always employ them.

Answer (score 5):

If array is static allocated:

```
size_t size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int);
```

if array is dynamic allocated(heap):

```
int *arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
```

where variable size is a dimension of the arr.

Comment: Dont ever use **size** name for identifier it may cause problems.

Answer (score 3):

`_msize(array)` in Windows or `malloc_usable_size(array)` in Linux should work for the dynamic array

Both are located within malloc.h and both return a size_t

Answer (score 0):

```
int len=sizeof(array)/sizeof(int);
```

Should work.

Comment: It works, however `site_t len = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);` it's a bit better (i.e. it still works when datatype of array elements has been changed.

Comment: @Grzegorz: Show us how it works for this array: `void f(int array[]) { site_t len = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]); }`

Comment: @Paul R: Why not? Unless `array` is an incomplete type (one case); if it's an array of `int` this will work.

Comment: @sbi: The poorly named `array` parameter is actually a pointer.

Comment: @caf: Yes, and that is something beginners keep running into. (I suppose a question like this _is_ from a beginner.)

Comment: @Charles: see sbi's answer as to why this only works for certain cases.

Comment: I didn't see sbi's first comment when I wrote mine. Yes, in C99 variable length arrays are a second case. Obviously if `array` isn't an array but is actually a pointer then it's not going to work but there was no indication that this might be the case in the answer.