# Array size determined at runtime

Tags: c, arrays, gcc, variable-length-array

I'm seeing some code like this:

```
int foo()
{
  int sz = call_other_func();
  char array[sz];

  /* whatever */
}
```

I'm baffled at how this would work and even compile with `gcc`. The size of the array is supposed to be *static* and determined at compile time, no?

Comment: As for how would it work -- why *wouldn't* it work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is size of variable length array computed at runtime in C99?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13908421/how-is-size-of-variable-length-array-computed-at-runtime-in-c99)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Declare an array with a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19131712/declare-an-array-with-a-variable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is valid C99 feature called [variable length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)(*VLA*), if you compile with `gcc -std=c90 -pedantic` you will receive the following warning:

> warning: ISO C90 forbids variable length array ‘array’ [-Wvla]

using `-std=c99 -pedantic` will not produce a warning, although both `gcc` and `clang` support *VLA* outside of *C99* mode and also in *C++* which does not allow *VLA* as an [extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html).

We can see from the [C99 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.7.5.2` *Array declarators* paragraph *4* says (*emphasis mine*):

> If the size is not present, the array type is an incomplete type. If the size is * instead of being an expression, the array type is a variable length array type of unspecified size, which can only be used in declarations with function prototype scope;124) such arrays are nonetheless complete types. If the size is an integer constant expression and the element type has a known constant size, the array type is not a variable length array type; **otherwise, the array type is a variable length array type.**

Note that [Visual Studio does not support VLA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zb1574zs.aspx) even though they  [now support C99](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/07/19/c99-library-support-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

This type of arrays are called [variable length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (you would also like to raed: [Arrays of Variable Length - GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html)) and are allowed in C99 only. By using VLAs, the size of the array can be determine at runtime.

Comment: Although people are upvoting this answer, don't know why reputation is not added to my profile?

Comment: Look like you are [rep capped](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32160/what-is-the-daily-reputation-cap-and-how-can-i-hit-it), congrats.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour; Thanks. But many of the users are getting reputation around 275 or even more in a single day(I saw this), how?

Comment: I changed the link I provided to a better answer so you might have seen the old one, the answer to the meta question says `You can still earn rep by winning a bounty, accepting an answer, or having one of your answers accepted, and downvotes will still count against you.` If you don't spend much time on meta at this point you probably should.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour; I have not get any of the `epic` or legendary badge! I hit +200 many times but that reputation never goes beyond 231. (I see you also got 261 rep once).

Comment: You have to hit your rep cap 50 times for epic and 200 times for legendary, that will usually take a while.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour; Until then I have to wait for getting reputation more than `231`. right?

Answer (score 4):

"In programming, a variable-length array (or VLA) is an array data structure of automatic storage duration whose length is determined at run time (instead of at compile time)." ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array))

They're supported in C99 (and subsequently in C11).

Read more about how it works: [The New C: Why Variable-length Arrays?](http://www.drdobbs.com/the-new-cwhy-variable-length-arrays/184401444)