# fgets doesn't stop getting input C

Tags: c

I created a function that checks if a given string is a number or not.
The problem is that I take the input with `fgets` but ,when called, it doesn't stop to take input from user!
I tried to fix adding `fflush(stdin)` and `fflush(stdout)` to fix because I read some stuffs online but isn't working :S

`getInput` calls the `fgets` that stores the string taken from user input then `isInt` checks if it's an int or not.
The problem is that the program stucks on the first `fgets`.

```
int isInt (char* string)
{ 
  int k=0;
  while( string[k] != '\0')
  {
    if ( isdigit(string[k])==0) //it's k++ here, I copied bad
      return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

void getInput(char* string)
{
    printf("Insert a number : \n");
    while (1)
    {
       fflush(stdout); //Tried to fix
       fflush(stdin); //same as above
       fgets(string,sizeof(string),stdin); //stucks here
        if(isInt(string)==0 )
        {
            printf("Ok it's a number!\n");
            break;
        }
        else printf("Insert a valid number!\n");;
    }
}
```

Comment: `while( string[k] != '\0')` - you'll probably want to increment `k` at some point to avoid an infinite loop. `sizeof(string)` is the size of a pointer, and almost certainly not what you want to pass to `fgets`.

Comment: Check the return value of `fgets()`. Always check return values of read functions. (`fgets()`, `scanf()`, `fread()`, ...)

Comment: @Crowman you're right, I copied bad but the right line was "isdigit(string[k++])", I'll edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `fgets()` will put newline character read from the stream into the array, so remove that to avoid `isInt` returning `1` seeing the newline character.
- `sizeof(string)` is the size of pointer, not the size of pointed buffer. You will have to receive the size of buffer separately. For more information, see [C sizeof a passed array - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493281/c-sizeof-a-passed-array).
- `fflush(stdin);` invokes *undefined behavior*, so you shouldn't use that.
- You have to increment `k` in the loop in `isInt`, or it may stuck into an infinite loop. (thanks @Crowman)

```
#include <string> // for using strchr()

int isInt (char* string)
{ 
  int k=0;
  while( string[k] != '\0')
  {
    if ( isdigit(string[k])==0)
      return 1;
    k++; // increment k
  }
  return 0;
}

void getInput(char* string, size_t string_max) // add parameter to get buffer size
{
    printf("Insert a number : \n");
    while (1)
    {
       fflush(stdout);
       fgets(string,string_max,stdin); // use passed buffer size instead of sizeof()
       char* lf = strchr(string, '\n'); // find newline character
       if (lf != NULL) *lf = '\0'; // and remove that if it exists
        if(isInt(string)==0 )
        {
            printf("Ok it's a number!\n");
            break;
        }
        else printf("Insert a valid number!\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Better to return some indication that the `fgets()` returned `NULL` or not.  Useful to avoid UB of `strchr(string, '\n')` when `string` was not populated.

Comment: Very useful thanks Mike! Btw I didn't get these two lines : "char* lf = strchr(string, '\n'); " and " if (lf != NULL) *lf = '\0';"

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should put the fgets inside the while condition:

```
while(fgets(string,sizeof(string),stdin))
```

Comment: This is a good point, but won't solve the problem only by this.