# How to printf all elements of table (int)

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, printf, sizeof

I try to display all values of tab but only 8 first elements are displayed no more

```
int tab[] = {0,2,5,3,9,0,8,9,2,0,4,3,0};
printf("taille %d: \n", sizeof(tab));

    for (int i=0; i<sizeof(tab); i++)
    {
        printf("indice : %d et valeur :%d \n", i, *(tab + i ));
    }
```

Comment: what is sizeof(tab)?

Comment: The `sizeof` operator returns the size in ***bytes***. If sizeof(int)` is `4` (which is the most common) then `sizeof(tab)` will be `52` bytes, so you'll loop over 52 elements in your 13-element array. Which will be way out of bounds.

Comment: On another note, why `*(tab + i )`? Why not `tab[i]`?

Comment: It will actually print 52 elements on most systems (causing undefined behavior). Post the actual code you tested. I'm guessing that in that code `tab` is actually a pointer.

Comment: `sizeof(tab)` -> `sizeof(tab) / sizeof(tab[0])`

Comment: "only 8 first elements" looks weird. This might be your actual problem: [C sizeof a passed array - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493281/c-sizeof-a-passed-array)

Comment: Please show the real code. Something that can be compiled and reproduces the problem. According to your comment to a given answer, this is not showing the code you actually use.

Comment: Your current code (after edits) should only print *one* element, since both `sizeof( tab )` and `sizeof( *tab )` will give the same result (since both a pointers), meaning that `size_tab` will be equal to `1`.

Comment: Furthermore, `*(tab + i)` is still exactly the same a `tab[i]` (it's defined in the C specification). And `tab[i]` is a pointer to an `int` so the `%d` format will be wrong. Not to mention that the function-argument `tab` doesn't match the argument you really pass to the function (in the `main` function the type of the expression `&tab` is `int (*)[13]`), very different from `int *[]` which is the same as `int **`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sizeof(tab)` yields the size in bytes of all the array `tab` that contains `13` elements each of them having the size equal to `sizeof( int )` (that is the same as `sizeof( *tab )`). That is

`sizeof(tab)` is equal to `13 * sizeof( int )` that in turn can be equal to `52` provided that `sizeof( int )` is equal to `4`.

But you need to output only 13 elements of the array.

So you should write for example

```
int tab[] = {0,2,5,3,9,0,8,9,2,0,4,3,0};
const size_t N = sizeof( tab ) / sizeof( *tab );

printf( "taille %zu: \n", N );

for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
{
    printf( "indice : %zu et valeur :%d \n", i, *(tab + i ) );
}
putchar( '\n' );
```

Pay attention to that to output an object of the type `size_t` you need to use the conversion specifier `zu`.

Here is a demonstrative program where the array output is placed in a separate function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

FILE * output( const int tab[], size_t n, FILE *fp )
{
    fprintf( fp, "taille %zu: \n", n );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        fprintf( fp, "indice : %zu et valeur :%d \n", i, *(tab + i ) );
    }
    
    return fp;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int tab[] = {0,2,5,3,9,0,8,9,2,0,4,3,0};
    const size_t N = sizeof( tab ) / sizeof( *tab );

    fputc( '\n', output( tab, N, stdout ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
taille 13: 
indice : 0 et valeur :0 
indice : 1 et valeur :2 
indice : 2 et valeur :5 
indice : 3 et valeur :3 
indice : 4 et valeur :9 
indice : 5 et valeur :0 
indice : 6 et valeur :8 
indice : 7 et valeur :9 
indice : 8 et valeur :2 
indice : 9 et valeur :0 
indice : 10 et valeur :4 
indice : 11 et valeur :3 
indice : 12 et valeur :0
```

Comment: OK with your solution but how to do a function with tab parameter

Comment: @langme See my updated post.

Comment: i saw my probem that i computed the size of tab in the output() function

Comment: @langme Within your function you are dealing with a pointer because the array passed to the function is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element.

Comment: @langme It is a bad idea. Return the previous content of the question. Otherwise answers do not corresponds to the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229397/discussion-between-langme-and-vlad-from-moscow).

Comment: @langme I do not take part in chats. Just restore the previous question.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
printf("taille %d: \n", sizeof(tab));
```

invokes *undefined behavior*, allowing anything to happen, by passind data having wrong type to `printf()`. `%d` expects `int`, but `sizeof` returns `size_t`. The correct format specifier to print `size_t` in decimal is `%zu`.

Then, `sizeof(tab)` is the size of the array `tab` in bytes (number of `char`, strictly speaking). It is not the number of elements. To obtain the number of elements, you have to divide that by the size of one element `sizeof(*tab)`.

```
int tab[] = {0,2,5,3,9,0,8,9,2,0,4,3,0};
printf("taille %zu: \n", sizeof(tab));

for (int i=0; i<sizeof(tab)/sizeof(*tab); i++)
{
    printf("indice : %d et valeur :%d \n", i, *(tab + i ));
}
```

Comment: with your code i have in result : indice 0 value 0 and indice 1 value 2 only printed

Comment: @langme I have correct result: [https://wandbox.org/permlink/RlnD3RJGMwAsigOV](https://wandbox.org/permlink/RlnD3RJGMwAsigOV)

Comment: works if i put all in main function but doesn't work if i make a display function...

Comment: @langme in that case you failed to show us your code. Using an array that was passed as parameter is something completely different than what you showed us. In that case follow the link that was given my MikeCAT as comment half an hour ago.

Comment: @langme Then my guess is that the "array" is really a pointer, and `sizeof(any_pointer)` will be the size of the pointer itself, not whatever it might point to. This fits with your claim that it only prints 8 elements, as the size of a pointer on a 64-bit system typically is 8 bytes.