# passing 'person [4]' to parameter of incompatible type 'person'

Tags: c, compiler-errors, cs50

Here I'm trying to write a c programming below,Here I created a data type **person** which has two arguments name and number (creating a name of the candidate and votes they have recieved), and when prompt for input,if user enters the name in the array of person data_type and number corresponds to that number should increase,but I got stuck in this error below.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cs50.h>
#include<string.h>
//Making person variable
typedef struct
{
    string name;
    int number;

}
person;

int update_vote(string name,person arr);

int main(void)
{
    person cand[4];
    cand[0].name="Brian";
    cand[1].name="David";
    cand[2].name="Obama";
    cand[3].name="Biden";
    
    cand[0].number=0;
    cand[1].number=0;
    cand[2].number=0;
    cand[3].number=0;
    
    //print the candidate names on the screen
    float len=sizeof(cand)/sizeof(cand[0]);
    int yu =(int) len;
    printf("Candidates Who are participating:");
    printf("\n");
    for (int i=0;i<yu;i++)
    {
      printf("%i.%s ",i+1,cand[i].name); 
    }
    printf("\n");
    
    //prompt for voters and take votes and update
    int voters=get_int("Enter the number of voters:");
    
    for (int j=0;j<voters;j++)
    {
        string vote=get_string("Enter your vote:");
        int update=update_vote(vote,cand);
        if (update!=-1)
        {
            cand[update].number++;
        }
        else{
            printf("Invalid name entered");
        }
    }
    
    printf("%d",cand);
    
}

int update_vote(string name,person arr)
{
     float len=sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
     int yu =(int) len;
     for(int i=0;i<yu;i++)
     {
         if (strcmp((name,arr[i].name)==0))
         {
             return i;
         }
     }
     return -1;
}
```

But got stuck in figuring out why the error is occuring below

**error: passing 'person [4]' to parameter of incompatible type 'person'
int update=update_vote(vote,cand);**

Comment: There are no fractional-length arrays.  `len` should be int or size_t.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because you are passing `person*` where `person` is expected as an argument.

You should change the type of argument so that it can receive (a pointer to) an array.

Also note that [`sizeof` cannot be used to determing the number of elements of arrays passed as arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493281/c-sizeof-a-passed-array). You should pass the number of elements separately.

Another point is that `printf("%d",cand);` will invoke *undefined behavior* because data having wrong type is passed. `%d` expects `int`. If you want to print a pointer, you should cast it to `void*` and use `%p` format specifier.

Try this:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cs50.h>
#include<string.h>
//Making person variable
typedef struct
{
    string name;
    int number;

}
person;

int update_vote(string name,person* arr,int arrSize); /* fix arguments */

int main(void)
{
    person cand[4];
    cand[0].name="Brian";
    cand[1].name="David";
    cand[2].name="Obama";
    cand[3].name="Biden";
    
    cand[0].number=0;
    cand[1].number=0;
    cand[2].number=0;
    cand[3].number=0;
    
    //print the candidate names on the screen
    float len=sizeof(cand)/sizeof(cand[0]);
    int yu =(int) len;
    printf("Candidates Who are participating:");
    printf("\n");
    for (int i=0;i<yu;i++)
    {
      printf("%i.%s ",i+1,cand[i].name); 
    }
    printf("\n");
    
    //prompt for voters and take votes and update
    int voters=get_int("Enter the number of voters:");
    
    for (int j=0;j<voters;j++)
    {
        string vote=get_string("Enter your vote:");
        int update=update_vote(vote,cand,yu); /* pass the number of elements */
        if (update!=-1)
        {
            cand[update].number++;
        }
        else{
            printf("Invalid name entered");
        }
    }
    
    printf("%p",(void*)cand); /* use correct way to print a pointer */
    
}

int update_vote(string name,person* arr,int arrSize) /* fix arguments */
{
     int yu =arrSize; /* use the passed size instead of sizeof */
     for(int i=0;i<yu;i++)
     {
         if (strcmp((name,arr[i].name)==0))
         {
             return i;
         }
     }
     return -1;
}
```

Comment: could you plz explain the cause of the problem,if you don't mind.

Comment: @Omkar I already explained that: the type of the argument `arr` is wrong.

Comment: yes but I didn't got what you told, Is it because we should use * symbol while using a data type which was created locally within that program?

Comment: @Omkar No. Generally an argument having type `some_type` cannot receive an array of `some_type`. Arrays are (usually) passed as a pointer to their first element in C. Threfore you will need an argument of a pointer `some_type*`.

Comment: Is it possible to print entire array of person data_type without the usage of FOR loop

Comment: @Omkar Yes, using `while` loop. `for (A; B; C) D` is (almost) equivalent to `A; while(B) {D C; }`.

Comment: yes but without usage of any loop,can we print entire array using printf only

Comment: @Omkar If the number of elements is known, you can do that by giving all things to print like `printf("%s %d\n%s %d\n%s %d\n%s %d\n", cand[0].name, cand[0].number, cand[1].name, cand[1].number, cand[2].name, cand[2].number, cand[3].name, cand[3].number);`

Answer (score 0):

Because **person cand[4];** , when you use " int update=update_vote(vote,cand);" , it means 'person *' that it's pointer.