# c - sizeof arrays in function decleration

Tags: arrays, c, function, pointers, sizeof

I've been given this code:

```
void f1(int** p1);
void f2(int p2[][]);
void f3(int p3[3][5]);
```

we can assume that `sizeof(int) = 4, sizeof(void*) = 8` 
and I needed to choose all the correct answers from these answers:

1. `sizeof(p3) == 3*8, sizeof(*p3) == 5*4, sizeof(**p3) == 4`
2. `sizeof(p2) == 8, sizeof(*p2) == 8, sizeof(**p2) == 4`
3. `sizeof(p1) == 8, sizeof(*p1) == 8, sizeof(**p1) == 4`
4. `sizeof(p1) == 8, sizeof(*p1) == 8, sizeof(**p1) == 8`
5. `sizeof(p3) == 8, sizeof(*p3) == 8, sizeof(**p3) == 4`
6. `sizeof(p3) == 8, sizeof(*p3) == 5*4, sizeof(**p3) == 4`
7. `sizeof(p2) == 8, sizeof(*p2) == 8, sizeof(**p2) == 8`

so I chose answers no. 2, 3, 6 and I was correct on 3 and 6, but 2 was wrong.
Would be glad for explanation why 2 is wrong, and only 3 and 6 are correct.

Comment: `p2` is an invalid declaration - none of the given answers for `p2` are correct.  `p2[][]` does not translate to `**p2`.

Comment: `int p3[3][5]` can be given as `int p3[][5]` but only the outermost dimension can be omitted. Otherwise the compiler won't know how to index the supposed array.

Comment: "c - sizeof arrays" --> With `void f1(int** p1); void f2(int p2[][]); void f3(int p3[3][5]);`, none of `p1, p2, p3` are _arrays_.  `p1, p3` are _pointers_.  `p2` does not compile.  Arrays are not pointers.  Pointers are not arrays.

Comment: And see [**C sizeof a passed array**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493281/c-sizeof-a-passed-array), along with the question it's linked to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This declaration of the parameter

```
void f2(int p2[][]);
```

is invalid in C. The right most subscript operator must have an expression.

You could write for example

```
void f2(int p2[*][*]);
```

but in this case you may not dereference pointers. Such a declaration may be present only in a function declaration that is not a function definition.

Instead you could write for example

```
void f2( size_t n, int p2[*][n]);
```

In this case within the function `sizepf( p2 )` will be equal to `8`, `sizeof( *p2 )` will be equal to `n * sizeof( int )` and `**p2` will be equal to `sizeof( int )`.

Comment: I think that I got you. Thank you!