# How do I get the number of elements a char array points to?

Tags: c

I was researching but could not find a way. I am passing 2 `char array pointers` to a function and fill those 2 arrays with values. Is there a way to get the size of the filled arrays?

I tried `size_t size = sizeof(*arguments)/sizeof(arguments[0])` already but that gave me 1 as a result, I know why its giving me 1 as result by researching but I just couldn't find a way to get the proper array length(the value how much elements are in the array). If that is not possible how can I work around this ? I need to know this because, I wanna give the last value of any array a `NUL`L for my `exec` functions.
My programs works as follows:

An user inputs 2 program names which are executed.
But the 2 programs are separated by a `";"`. So I have 2 arrays which can vary in size , which depends on the input in the terminal.

```
void getArguments(char * [],char * [], int ,char * []);

  int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
     pid_t pid,pid2;
     char * arguments2[argc/2+1];
     char * arguments[argc/2+1];

     getArguments(arguments, arguments2,argc,argv);

     if((pid=fork())==-1){
        printf("Error");
     }
     else if(pid == 0){

        execvp(arguments[0],arguments);
     }

     else{
      if((pid2 = fork())== -1){
        printf("Error" );
      }
      else if(pid2 == 0 ){

        execvp(arguments2[0],arguments2);
      }
      else{
        int status;
        wait(&status);
        exit(0);
      }
     }
    return 0;
  }


  void getArguments(char * arguments[], char * arguments2[],int argc, char * argv[]){
      int i=0;

      while(strcmp(argv[i+1],";")!=0){
      arguments[i] = argv[i+1];
      i++;
      }
      arguments[argc/2-1]= NULL;

      int j = i+2;
      int k = 0;

      for( ;j<=argc; j++){
      arguments2[k] = argv[j];
      k++;
      }
      arguments2[argc/2-1]=NULL;
  }
```

Comment: Size of a pointer is the size of the pointer itself, not what it points to. If you have a null-terminated byte string use the `strlen` function, otherwise you have to keep track of the size yourself (through variables).

Comment: I guess you don't want to know the size of a char pointer, what you want is the count of elements inside an array.

Comment: @KamilCuk Indeed thats what I wanna know

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think I phrased the question a bit wrong, I want to know how much elements are in the array to which the pointer is pointing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [size of array in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545428/size-of-array-in-c)

Comment: Your code is clear - you know the count of initialized elements of `arguments` and `arguments2` arrays inside `getArguments` function, you store them inside `i` and `k` variables.

Comment: If all you have is a pointer, and the pointer isn't to a null-terminated string, then you can't. It's as simple as that. If the array have another custom terminator then you could find that to figure out the number of elements (basically what `strlen` does for null-terminated strings).

Comment: @KamilCuk Oh wait I think you are right, thats the size I dont know how I couldnt figure that out...

Comment: I guess you're just facing the Array decay to pointer idiom. Arrays used as arguments are automatically cast to pointers and carry on no information about its length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't get the size of an array if you only have a pointer. You must pass the size as a separate argument to your function.

EDIT: I now understand you need to *return* from your function the number elements used in the array. You can either add two integer pointer variables that receive the size, or you could set the first unused element to NULL so the caller knows when it is at the end of the filled portion.

For example:

```
 char * arguments2[argc];  // as you don't know the result, do not divide by 2: it may be too small!
 char * arguments[argc];
 int size1=0, size2=0;

 getArguments(arguments, &size1, arguments2, &size2, argc, argv);
```

And:

```
void getArguments(char *arguments[], int *size1, char *arguments2[], int *size2, int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // ...
    *size1= i;
    //...
    *size2= j;
}
```

Comment: But the array gets filled in the function, so I cant actually know how big the array will be, Is there a workaround or something?

Comment: If you're filling the array then you yourslef know the size...

Comment: @Nina But the size varys, it depends on the input on the terminal.

Comment: Your `main` provided (or should provide) the arrays of the appropriate size. `main` knows the size of the `argv` array from `argc`. Your `getArguments` just uses the arrays provided by `main`.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Okay I have to show hwo the prog should work I guess.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I edited my question so you understand why I need the size of one array.