# Pointer to specified number of values

Tags: objective-c, pointers

How can I specify that a method should take as parameter a pointer to a location in memory that can hold a specified number of values? For example, if I have:

```
- (void)doSomethingWith:(int *)values;
```

I'd like to make it clear that the `int *` passed in should point to an allocated space in memory that's able to hold 10 such values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To directly answer your question, use an array argument with a bounds, e.g.:

```
- (void)takeTenInts:(int[10])array
```

Which *specifies* that the method takes an array of 10 integers.

Only problem is the C family of languages do not do bounds checking, so the following is valid:

```
int a[10], b[5];

[self takeTenInts:a]; // ok
[self takeTenInts:b]; // oops, also ok according to the compiler
```

So while you are *specifying* the size, as you wish to do, that specification is not being enforced.

If you wish to *enforce* the size you can use a `struct`:

```
typedef struct
{
   int items[10];
} TenInts;

- (void)takeTenInts(TenInts)wrappedArray
```

Now this doesn't actually *enforce* the size at all[*], but its as close a you can get with the C family (to which the word "enforcement" is anathema).

If you just wish to *know* the size, either pass it as an additional argument or use `NSArray`.

[*] It is not uncommon to see structures in C following the pattern:

```
typedef struct
{
   // some fields
   int data[0];
} someStruct;
```

Such structures are dynamically allocated based on their size (`sizeof(someStruct)`) *plus* enough additional space to store sufficient integers (e.g. `n * sizeof(int)`).

In other words, specifying an array as the last field of a structure does **not** enforce in anyway that there is space for exactly that number of integers; there may be space for more, or fewer...

Answer (score 1):

Why use "`(int *)`" when you have the power (and "`count`") of "`NSArray`" to work with?

But anyways, [looking at this potentially related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773328/how-to-find-the-size-of-integer-array), couldn't you just do a "`sizeof(values)`" to get the size of a statically/globally allocated pointer?

If that doesn't work (which would be in the case of a dynamically allocated array), you really would probably need some kind of "count:" parameter in your "`doSomethingWith:`" method declaration.

Comment: So it's not possible to specify how large the memory pointed to should be?

Comment: If you're doing the allocating at run time and are not passing in the size (or count of ints) as a parameter to that function, then no.

Comment: +1 for `NSArray` (or other high-level solution). However, be careful with `sizeof()` suggestions. They can be confusing. For instance, it doesn't matter how an array was allocated (static/global/auto vs. heap). It matters that the type is still an array or has it been demoted to just a pointer. In the scope of `int foo[7];`, then `sizeof(foo)/sizeof(foo[0])` gives 7, but pass `foo` to a function and that function can't use `sizeof` to figure out the length because it's received a pointer, not an array. Attempts to use `sizeof` will give bogus results (effectively `sizeof(int*)/sizeof(int)`).

Answer (score 1):

There are a several ways.  You could just name the method appropriately:

```
- (void)doSomethingWithTenInts:(int *)tenInts;
```

Or you could use a struct:

```
typedef struct {
    int values[10];
} TenInts;

- (void)doSomethingWithTenInts:(TenInts *)tenInts;
```

Or you could make the user tell you how many `int`s he is giving you:

```
- (void)doSomethingWithInts:(int *)ints count:(int)count;
```