# functions calling from main method objective c

Tags: objective-c, function, main-method

Here I need to write a function which is called from main method with integer array as a parameter please give me example.

In below example parameter are int type.

**Note** : please tell this is correct way to do this or not...

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

void displayit (int);

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        int i;

        for (i=0; i<5; i++)
        {
                displayit( i );
        }

   }
   return 0;
}

void displayit (int i)
{
        int y = 0;

        y += i;

        NSLog (@"y + i = %i", y);
}
```

Thanks in advance....

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried out these, please check.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

void displayit (int array[], int len);

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        int array[]={1,2,3};
        displayit( array, 3 );
    }
    return 0;
}

void displayit (int array[], int len)
{
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
        NSLog(@"display %d : %d",i,array[i]);
    }
}
```

The out put is:

```
2014-10-30 14:09:32.017 OSTEST[32541:77397] display 0 : 1
2014-10-30 14:09:32.018 OSTEST[32541:77397] display 1 : 2
2014-10-30 14:09:32.018 OSTEST[32541:77397] display 2 : 3
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

I used another parameter `len` to avoid boundary beyond.

> If the array is a global, static, or automatic variable (int array[10];), then sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]) works. [Quoted From Another Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773328/how-to-find-the-size-of-integer-array)

Comment: Pls tell its necessary or not to declare  void displayit (int array[], int len) before main function and also why you add void.

Comment: If you do not declare the function before main, you would get the following errors(or warnings). It is rule of C, as well followed by Objective-C. ///Users/Sinri/Codes/WebProjects/overstack/OSTEST/OSTEST/main.m:17:9: Implicit declaration of function 'displayit' is invalid in C99
///Users/Sinri/Codes/WebProjects/overstack/OSTEST/OSTEST/main.m:22:6: Conflicting types for 'displayit'
///Users/Sinri/Codes/WebProjects/overstack/OSTEST/OSTEST/main.m:17:9: Previous implicit declaration is here

Comment: What's more needs checking?

Comment: i want to pass an array in function and return array in output...not able to post my code can you given any email_id or chat id to ask its very helpful...

Comment: What do you mean the 'return'? Do you want to contain `return array;` in the function?

Comment: find the code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26655375/passing-int-array-and-return-array-in-output-using-objective-c