# How do I find the number of bytes used by a pointer?

Tags: c++, c, objective-c, pointers

I have a pointer (uint8_t *myPointer), that I pass as parameter to a method, and then this method sets a value to this pointer, but I want to know how many bytes are used (pointed at ?) by the myPointer variable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Stefan - can you add a link to the duplicate?

Comment: @ChrisF - Sure! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975128/sizeof-an-array-in-the-c-programming-language

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The size of the pointer: `sizeof(myPointer)` (Equal to `sizeof(uint8_t*)`)
The size of the pointee: `sizeof(*myPointer)` (Equal to `sizeof(uint8_t)`)

If you meant that this points to an array, there is no way to know that. A pointer just points, and cares not where the value is from.

To pass an array via a pointer, you'll need to also pass the size:

```
void foo(uint8_t* pStart, size_t pCount);

uint8_t arr[10] = { /* ... */ };
foo(arr, 10);
```

You can use a template to make passing an entire array easier:

```
template <size_t N>
void foo(uint8_t (&pArray)[N])
{
    foo(pArray, N); // call other foo, fill in size.
    // could also just write your function in there, using N as the size
}

uint8_t arr[10] = { /* ... */ };
foo(arr); // N is deduced
```

Comment: +1 -- but it should be noted that if `foo` is a big function you'll incur code bloat with the template if the number of different values of N is large. You can mitigate this by making foo a stub which calls an overload of foo accepting an explicit length parameter.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. You must pass the size of the buffer pointed to by the pointer yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Unless the array is instantiated at compile time. Example `int test[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};` In that case, you can use `sizeof(test)` to return you the correct size. Otherwise, it's impossible to tell the size of an array without storing a counter of your own.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean the memory needed for the pointer only. You can check this at compile time with `sizeof(myPointer)`.