# int array size changes

Tags: c, arrays, int

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sizeof an array in the C programming language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975128/sizeof-an-array-in-the-c-programming-language)

Why is the size of my int array changing when passed into a function?

I have this in my main:

```
int numbers[1];
numbers[0] = 1;
printf("numbers size %i", sizeof(numbers));
printSize(numbers);
return 0;
```

and this is the printSize method

```
void printSize(int numbers[]){
printf("numbers size %i", sizeof(numbers));}
```

You can see that I dont do anything else to the numbers array but the size changes when it gets to the printSize method...? If I use the value of *numbers it prints the right size...?

Comment: Many duplicates on SO already, e.g. [Sizeof an array in the C programming language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975128/sizeof-an-array-in-the-c-programming-language)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any array argument to a function will decay to a *pointer to the first element of the array*. So in actual fact, your function `void printSize(int[])` effectively has the signature `void printSize(int*)`. In full, it's equivalent to:

```
void printSize(int * numbers)
{
    printf("numbers size %i", sizeof(numbers));
}
```

Writing this way hopefully makes it a bit clearer that you are looking at the size of a pointer, and not the original array.

As usual, I recommend [the C book's](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter5/arrays_and_address_of.html) explanation of this :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're just getting the size of the pointer to an int. Arrays are just fancy syntax for pointers and offsets.

Comment: We need a "don't parse HTML with regex" equivalent for that assertion.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth : "arrays" are not pointers, but it is true that the "array syntax" in C is just syntactic sugare for `*(ptr + index)` !! -1 if I could to the comment

Comment: Right. I would have thought it was obvious that I meant the array *syntax* when I was talking about something being "fancy syntax" for something else...

Comment: That completely fails to explain how the first part of their code works as they expected, but not the second.