# Why it gives wrong array size

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sizeof an array in the C programming language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975128/sizeof-an-array-in-the-c-programming-language)

I have been working on this for long, but can't seem to understand why this is happening.

```
void fun(char []);

void fun(char a[])

{

   printf("Size is %d\n",sizeof(a));

}

int main ()

{

  char arr[10] = { 0 };

  printf("Size is %d\n",sizeof(arr));

  fun(arr);  

  return 0;

}
```

Why is the Output:

Size is 10

Size is 4

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975128/sizeof-an-array-in-the-c-programming-language

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because `arrays` when passed in functions get decayed into pointers in functions.

`sizeof` in `fun()` returns the size of the pointer `a`. Read about [Arrays and Pointers](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/c-faq/c-2.html/).

`a` in `fun()` is actually a pointer copied by value.

You should pass the size of the array with as a separate argument.

You should try it this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void fun(char []);
void fun(char a[], int n)
{
//     printf("Size is %d\n",sizeof(arr));
       printf("Size is %d\n",n);
}
int main ()
{
  char arr[10] = { 0 };
  const int truesize = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); // try to understand this statement what it does -  sizeof returns size in bytes
  printf("Size is %d\n",truesize);
  fun(arr,truesize);  // This is how you should call fun
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why was this -- sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]) -- needed ??

Comment: Make the array of type `int` and see what size you get with your code.

Answer (score 5):

The first `sizeof` reports the size of a pointer, the second the size of an array.

A parameter declared with array syntax (`void fun(char [])`) is actually a pointer parameter. The `[]` is just syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 0):

sizeof is an operator, it computes it value at compile time. sizeof(char[]) is the size of the pointer.