# Writing a fast filtering function for a char **

Tags: c, algorithm

I'm trying to write a fast function for filtering a char ** and putting the results into another char **

This is what I have written:

```
/*
   -filterable is what is to be filtered
   -filter is the filter
   -filtered is the result applying the filter to filterable
*/
void filter(const char** filterable,const char * filter,char** filtered)
{
    memset(filtered,'\0',sizeof(filtered));
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    int filter_length=strlen(filter);
    int items=sizeof(filterable)/sizeof((char *) filterable); //segfault?

    while(items--)
    {
        if((strncmp(filter,filterable[i],filter_length)==0))
            strcpy(filtered[j++],filterable[i]);

        i++;
    }
}
```

The issue is I don't think I'm getting the number of rows from "filterable" properly as I'm getting a segfault.  Any suggestions? Is this the fastest approach to filtering a char **?

***Post-Comments:***

Okay I read everyone's comments and the below seems to be working.  Given this needs to be fast I threw in the register keyword although I've heard it doesn't guarantee anything these days.

```
void filter(char ** filterable, const char * filter, char ** filtered, int filters)
{
    register int i=0;
    register int j=0;
    int filter_length=strlen(filter);

    while(filters--)
    {
        if((strncmp(filter,filterable[i],filter_length)==0))
           strcpy(filtered[j++],filterable[i]);

        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: bad usage of `sizeof`. You're passing a pointer as argument to the operator `sizeof`. You need to pass the size in function arguments.

Comment: As this quetion is tagged C++, do you have any reason not to use C++ containers here, instead of raw buffers ? i.e: std::vector<std::string>

Comment: `sizeof(filterable)/sizeof((char *) filterable)` is always 1, since pointer to `char**` and to `char*` have the same size. If you want to know the number of elements in filterable, pass it as an argument to the function.

Comment: @Jem: This is nestled in C++ code, but I want to re-use it in ansi C at some point.  I removed the tag. Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've confusing pointers, arrays, and what pointers point to.

`memset(filtered, '\0', sizeof(filtered));` is probably giving you the segfault.  `filtered` is of type `char **`, which means that `sizeof(filtered)` is the size of a pointer, not anything pointed at, and you're setting `filtered`, which is a pointer to `char *`, to zero.  This is undefined behavior, but on most modern computers sets `filtered` to the null pointer.  You need to have memory allocated for what `filtered` points to, and what those `char *` point to, and you need to pass in how big `filtered` is and how big the string areas it points to are.

Since `filtered` contains an invalid memory address, trying to `strcpy()` anything to
it or anything it ostensibly points to will try to access it, and that will normally give you a segfault on a Unix/Linux machine.

`sizeof(filterable)/sizeof(char *) filterable)` does nothing useful.  If `filterable` was an array, `sizeof(filterable)/sizeof(*filterable)` would give you the number of elements in `filterable`.  However, even if it was originally an array, it's passed as a pointer, and has lost all information about the number of elements it contains.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use sizeof(char**) (as the function actually receives), see [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491777/c-dynamic-memory-allocation-and-sizeof/5491855#5491855). You should give the length of the array as a parameter to the function.

Answer (score 0):

sizeof(filtered) is going to be 4 on the usual 32-bit machine. That is, sizeof(char**) == 4. Is that what you are looking for when you call memset( filtered,'\0',sizeof(filtered) ) ?

The segfault just might be arising from the fact that filtered == 0x0000 after you call memset().

-- pete