# Behaviour of Sizeof in C

Tags: c, arrays, sizeof

I have learnt that when we pass the array name to sizeof, the name of the array does not decay to the pointer to base address. The code below verifies this fact by giving answer 10.

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main(){  
    int arr[10];  
    printf("Size of array is %d" , sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int));  
    return 0;  
}
```

However when I run the code below, the answer comes 1. Irrespective of whether a dimension is written in prototype or not , the answer is 1. Why is it so ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void dimension(int arr[]){  
    printf("Sizof array is %d" , sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int));  
}


int main(){  
    int arr[10];  
    dimension(arr);  
    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: The standard says the array name in a function's arguments will be considered as a pointer. So `int arr[]` will be `int *arr`, and `int arr[][10]` will be `int (*p)[10]` (remaining size of a pointer). Aside: `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])` is better, when you change the type of arr, you won't have to modified this place.

Comment: @Stan: Should have been an answer, I think.

Comment: It produces 1 because you are working in a 32-bit environment where `sizeof(void *) == sizeof(int)`; in 64-bit environments, it would produce 2 normally because a pointer is 8 bytes but `int` remains 4 bytes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sizeof an array in the C programming language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975128/sizeof-an-array-in-the-c-programming-language)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This signature

```
void dimension(int arr[])
```

is **absolutely** equivalent to

```
void dimension(int *arr)
```

See also [Question 6.4](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrparam.html)

Answer (score 5):

Because you pass an array of unknown size which is equivalent to a pointer in this context. `sizeof` is calculated at **compile** time, not runtime.

Comment: Except for the Variable-Length Array (VLA) in C99, `sizeof` works like what you said.

Answer (score 3):

When array is passed to a function, it is passed as a pointer, not an array, so the `sizeof(arr)` will return `sizeof(int *)`

Comment: it is not the size of an `int` on x64

Comment: @unkulunkulu - it depends, and that's why I said usually.

Comment: I didn't notice the word "usually" :)

Comment: anyway, you can't say "usually" if it's not correct for x64 :D

Comment: "often" could be a more appropriate substitute, I guess. But I'm just advocating removing of that parenthesized part :)

Answer (score 2):

In

```
void dimension(int arr[]){  
    printf("Sizof array is %d" , sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int));  
}
```

`arr[]` decays to a pointer, therefore you have the equivalent of

```
printf("Sizof array is %d" , sizeof(int*)/sizeof(int));
```

and because on your platform, `sizeof(int*) == sizeof(int)`, you receive `1` as the result.

Note however, that for variable length arrays, `sizeof` becomes a runtime operation:

```
int main () {
    int i = ...;
    int x[i];
    printf("number of elements: %d", sizeof (x) / size(*x));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays as function arguments *do* decay to pointer, though. Since this happens before sizeof() is called, you can't prevent it.

Just think about it: how can sizeof() know the size of an array if any size array can be passed and no extra info is available? You get sizeof(pointer), and that seems to be the same size as an int, in your setup.

Answer (score 0):

because arr is a pointer, which is an integer .

Answer (score 0):

Because you're passing an unknown size array.

Comment: You need to provide a bit more explanation than "_Because you're passing an unknown size array_" to gain reputation.  The core of the answer is basically correct, but not sufficiently helpful to score.