# memset function in c language

Tags: c, arrays, memset

I am studying the memset function now, but all the examples are regarding to char array as following:

```
char a[100];
memset(a, 0, 100);
```

it will set every element in this char array to 0.

I wondered if memset can apply to int array or float array?

Comment: Even, `memset` can be applied to a `struct`. Any memory is OK, if you have right to write it.

Comment: why not just `char a[100] = {};` ?

Comment: what about an array of pointers?

Comment: @ratzip it would set all the pointers to NULL

Comment: @Muggen: Because that's not valid C... (You need a zero inside the braces to make it valid.)

Comment: @Fecal - It would set the pointers to 0, which likely is the same as NULL, but that is not guaranteed.

Comment: `memset(a, 0, sizeof a)` will set the contents of `a` to all-bytes-zero.  But unless `a` is an array of some integer type (note: char is an integer type), it's not guaranteed to set the values to zero.  It's *likely* that all-bytes-zero is a representation of 0.0 for a floating-point type, or a null pointer for a pointer type, but the language doesn't guarantee it.  To initialize an object to all-zeros, whatever its type, you can write `some_type a = { 0 };`.  (Some compilers may warn about missing initializers, but the unspecified elements *will* be set to zero.)

Comment: Will it `free` whatever the previous pointer was pointing to?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Yes, it can apply to any memory buffer, but you must input the correct memory buffer size ... `memset` treats any memory buffer as a series of bytes, so whether it's `char`, `int`, `float`, `double`, etc, doesn't really matter.  Keep in mind though that it will not set multi-byte types to a specific non-zero value ... for example:

```
int a[100];
memset(a, 1, sizeof(a));
```

will **not** set each member of `a` to the value 1 ... rather it will set *every byte* in the memory buffer taken up by `a` to `1`, which means every four-byte `int` will be set to the value `0x01010101`, which is not the same as `0x00000001`

Comment: Very helpful note on **multi-byte types**!

Comment: So, what do you do to set each member of `a` to value 1?

Comment: If you're using GCC there are some nice options here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Designated-Inits.htmlhere:

Answer (score 2):

For static-sized and variable-length arrays, you can just

```
<arbitrary-type>  foo [...];
memset (foo, 0, sizeof (foo)); // sizeof() gives size of entity in bytes
```

***Rule of thumb:*** Never hardcode [data sizes].

(This does not work if you pass arrays as function arguments: [Behaviour of Sizeof in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813473/behaviour-of-sizeof-in-c/6813522#6813522) )

Answer (score 1):

It can be applied to any array.  The 100 at the end is the size in bytes, so a integer would be 4 bytes each, so it would be -

```
int a[100];
memset(a, 0, sizeof(a)); //sizeof(a) equals 400 bytes in this instance
```

Get it? :)

Comment: PS: It's not just arrays, its arbitrary memory blocks, you're setting memory from location to value 0 for a length of 400 bytes in my example - it doesn't care what the memory was formatted as.

Comment: you really need to mention sizeof