# Constructing an array of unique characters from a char array

Tags: c, arrays, char

Suppose I have a char array and I want to construct a new one that only contains unique characters (i.e. the array contains only one occurrence of each character). This is part of a response to an exercise in an introductory C book where advanced concepts like pointers are not yet introduced. So, the answer should not make use of pointers.

```
int i, j, n;
char list[MAX_SIZE], unique_list[MAX_SIZE];
char curr;
n = 0;
for(i = 0; i < strlen(list) ; ++i){
    curr = list[i];
    for (j = 0; j <= n; ++j){
        if (unique_list[j] == curr)
            break;
        else
            unique_list[n++] = curr;
    }
}
```

When I run this however, it doesn't seem to work. Apparently it is stuck in a permanent loop and `unique_list[j]` is always equal to `curr` (the current character being read from the char array). However I am not initializing `unique_list` so why does it always contain the same characters as the ones being read from the main array?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33200985/how-to-separate-a-string-into-an-array-of-the-unique-characters-strings/33201687#33201687 ??

Comment: @user3386109 Great! I would have accepted this if it were written as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: I fixed up the answer by MASh, so that you have an answer to accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rethink the logic. For each character in the `list`, you need to check if that character is in the `unique_list`. If not, then add the character to the `unique_list`. In other words, adding the character needs to be after the `j` loop, not inside the `j` loop. Something like this:

```
int i, j, n;
char list[MAX_SIZE], unique_list[MAX_SIZE];
char curr;
n = 0;
for(i = 0; i < strlen(list) ; ++i){
    curr = list[i];
    for (j = 0; j < n; ++j){
        if (unique_list[j] == curr)
            break;
    }
    if(j == n) 
        unique_list[n++] = curr;
}
```

Comment: wait, I should look for once more time.

Comment: Yeah, j should change to n+1 when it gets unique character.

Comment: @user3386109, great job! I was lazy to describe enough.

Comment: Lazy persons are the inventor of  new-idea :v

Answer (score 1):

To do that in complexity O(n) use a flag array.
Here is the complete code

```
int i, j, n;
char list[MAX_SIZE], unique_list[MAX_SIZE];
int flag[128];
memset(flag,1, sizeof(flag));
char curr;
n = 0;
for(i = 0; i < strlen(list) ; ++i)
{
    curr = list[i];
    if(flag[curr]) {
        unique_list[n++] = curr;
        flag[curr] = 0;
    }
}
```

if you don't know what memset is you can check this [memset function in c language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6816431/memset-function-in-c-language)

Comment: I'd rather not use an advanced concept like `memset`. This is an exercise from an introductory chapter.