# C array not working properly

Tags: c

So I have an C string (array of chars) in my main method, when I pass it as parameter into another method, its size changes.

```
void method(char* arr){
    printf( "%u\n", sizeof(arr) ); //returns 4, in my program.
    arr = "hello "; //executes just fine
    char arr2[9] = "people";
    strcat(arr, arr2); // (1) here is where it crashes down
    int i = 0; while(i < sizeof(arr2)){ arr[i+6] = arr2[i]; i++;} // (2) this causes it to crashdown too
}

int main(){
    char array[33];
    printf("%u\n", sizeof(array) ); //returns 33, in my program.
    method(array);
}
```

Why does this happen?, how can I fix it? Does this mean I cannot add more values to the C string? I suspect this may be the cause of the constant crashdown of my program (whenever I try to add n).
Neither does the line marked by (1) nor (2) works. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Why are you using a C string in C++? And what prevented you from indenting your code?

Comment: Don't modify string literals...

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeof-a-pointer-pointing-to-an-array

Comment: I need to use a C string

Comment: @SofiaAlegre: Why's that then?

Comment: it is part of the requirements that I have

Comment: BTW, in English in this context, it's just "crashes". Not "crashes down".

Comment: @SofiaAlegre: Why? What requirements? From whom? Some detail, please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sizeof an array in the C programming language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975128/sizeof-an-array-in-the-c-programming-language)

Comment: FTFY. Got rid of iostream and now it's all pure C.

Comment: @CashCow: But the OP is using C++. Antiquated idioms yes, but C++. That means solutions like templates may be in scope; all we know is that C strings must be used, not that other C++ features cannot. I think your edit is far too broad.

Comment: I have to agree on what @LightnessRacesinOrbit said, although I don't mind much as long as everyone understands the transformed code.

Comment: @Sofia Alegre, if you want to do this in C++ we will rewrite it to use the C++ standard library. I don't really need to answer why your code doesn't work (in C) as others have already explained it.

Answer (score 8):

Here is what happens:

1. In `main()`, you're applying `sizeof()` to the array, so you get the size of the array.
2. When `main()` calls `method()`, the array [decays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying) into a pointer (since `method()` takes a pointer).
3. In `method()`, you are applying `sizeof()` to the pointer, so you get the size of the pointer.

To fix, pass the actual allocated size of `arr` into `method()` as an additional argument, and use that argument as a limit on how much stuff you're permitted to write into `arr`.

As a side note, the following doesn't do what you expect:

```
arr = "hello "; //executes just fine
```

This doesn't modify the underlying array; it simply re-points `arr` to the string literal. You should be using `strncpy()` instead of the assignment.

Answer (score 2):

Naturally,

```
cout << sizeof(arr) << endl; //returns 4, in my program.
```

prints 4, because here you are actually printing `sizeof(char*)`, i.e. the size of the pointer, while in the `main()` function you are doing the equivalent of `sizeof(sizeof(char) * 33)`.

**How to fix that**: well, the problem is your function signature:

```
void method(char* arr)
```

Working with functions that receives pointers to arrays requires you to add a parameter in the function signature to specify the size of the array:

```
void method(char* arr, int arr_size)
```

It's the only way.

Answer (score 2):

1. You're doing `sizeof` on a pointer, not on a array. You *cannot* pass an array by value into a function. You just can't.
2. You're then replacing the local copy of said pointer with a new one that points to `"hello"`. Then expecting to be able to get the 8th character of the string `"hello"` is obviously not going to work.

   - You're in C++. Use `std::string` and `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to know size in the function there are 3 ways:

- pass the length of the char array as the second parameter.
- use strlen function inside the method
- change method signature into `void method(const std::string& arr);` and you will be able to use `arr.size();` to get the size of the string. If you write in C++ the safer way is to use `std::string` instead of `char*`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are writing C++ (even though it is a *lot* like C), change "method" (poor choice for a name, if I may say so) to --

```
void method(char (&arr)[33]) // I would recommend std::string instead
{
    cout << sizeof(arr) << endl; // should return 33 in your program.
    strcpy(arr, "hello "); // should execute per behaviour defined by ISO
    char arr2[] = "people"; // Note that arr2 is followed by '[' and an immediate ']'
    strcat(arr, arr2); // Now this should work, although std::string is still better.
}
```

Note that even this is like C (because it uses vanilla character arrays rather than std::string).

Answer (score 0):

"Correct" code in C.

```
int method(char* arr, size_t size, bool useStrcat)
{
   const char * prefix = "hello "; // could be static
   size_t prefixLen = strlen( prefix ); // which will be 6. Could be static.
   strncpy( arr, "hello ", size );
   char arr2[] = "people";     
   if( useStrcat )
   {
       strncat(arr, arr2, size - prefixLen);  
   }
   else
   {
       for( int i = 0; i < sizeof(arr2) && i < (size - prefixLen); ++i )
       {
          arr[i+prefixLen] = arr2[i];
       }
   }
   return prefixLen + sizeof(arr2);
}
```

1. You pass in the size of your buffer.
2. Even if it is not big enough this function will never overflow it.
3. The strncat path is logically different when it will overflow the buffer. This will reserve the last character for the null terminator, but the for loop will not and will leave your string not null-terminated. The fix for that of course is to put ( size - prefixLen - 1 ) in the for loop then force a null terminator.

Note that arr2 includes its null terminator as part of its size so it will be written when your buffer does not reach capacity.

Many programs that do this will return for you the number of character they wanted to write and will often be called twice, the second time with a large enough buffer, and sometimes the first call is made purposely with a 0-size buffer just to obtain the count.

Test this method called from main by passing it:
- differing values for useStrcat
- a buffer size smaller than what you need for the output (in this case 13).

Beware of printing a not-terminated string though. Your "main" can always allocate 13 anyway and put in the null itself, e.g.

```
int main()
{
   char buf[13] = {0};
   method( buf, 12, false ); // do not use strcat
   puts( buf );
}
```