# Arrays and functions in c language

Tags: c, arrays, sizeof

There i something i dont get, if have the following:

```
double average (double scores[]){

 double sum = 0;
 int n;
 int nscores = sizeof(scores)/sizeof(double);
 for (n=0 ;n<nscores ;++n){
 sum+=scores [n];
 return sum/nscores;
}
```

and i send this function an array like this:

```
  double scores[3]={1,2,3};
```

why will sizeof(scores)  will be 0?

Comment: If your question is about C, then why did you use the tag `c++`?

Comment: And `sizeof(scores)` won't be 0. It'll be the size of a pointer. This has been asked a milion times.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit because they are much alike

Comment: dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975128/sizeof-an-array-in-the-c-programming-language

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit but sum/nscores = 0/0 meaning nscores is 0 meaning sizeof(scores) is 0? or is it sizeof(void*) ?

Comment: @Itzik984 It will be (4/8) or whatever your compiler sizes for a pointer and double. But since they are both ints the answer is also an int. (4/8)=0 in c integer math.

Comment: Where's the division operation in `sizeof(scores)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sizeof(scores)`, inside the function, is equivalent to `sizeof(double *)`: the compiler has no way to tell, at that point, how big the array was.

It *won't* be zero, but because `sizeof(scores)` and `sizeof(double)` are both integer-type expressions, `sizeof(scores)/sizeof(double)` is integer division, so if `sizeof(scores) < sizeof(double)`, then `sizeof(scores)/sizeof(double) == 0.`

Comment: so why do i get a 0? sizeof(scores)=sizeof(void*)=4? and the division is 0?

Comment: @Itzik984: Yes, exactly. On your platform, `sizeof(double *)` is `4` and `sizeof(double)` is `8`, so `sizeof(scores)/sizeof(double)` is `4/8`, which is `0`.

Answer (score 3):

This is because array as a parameter of the function is treated as pointer. For example,

```
double average (double scores[]);
```

... is an equivalent to:

```
double average (double *scores);
```

and so `sizeof(scores)/sizeof(double)` is equal to `sizeof(double *)/sizeof(double)`, and if you happen to have those types to be of the same size, the result is `1`, but if size of double is 8 and pointer is just 4, then result is `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Two things to remember about arrays in C:

1. Except when it is the operand of a `sizeof` or unary `&` operator, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration, an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" will be replaced with ("decay to") an expression of type "pointer to `T`" whose value is the address of the first element of the array.
2. In the context of a function parameter declaration, `T a[]` and `T a[N]` are identical to `T *a`; IOW, `a` is declared as a pointer to `T`, not as an array.  Note that this is only true for function parameter declarations.

When you call `average(scores)` from your main function, the expression `scores` will be replaced with another expression of type `double *`, so what `average` receives is a *pointer* value, not an array.  Thus, the `sizeof` trick to get the number of elements won't work within the `average` function.  You will have to pass the number of elements in `scores` as a separate parameter, like so:

```
double average(double *scores, size_t count)
{
   ...
}
```

and call it as

```
average(scores, sizeof scores / sizeof *scores); // or pass a constant 3, or
                                                 // something similar.
```

Answer (score 0):

`scores` is a double *const, hence `sizeof(scores)` will be size required to store a pointer