# Number of bytes in void pointer

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers

Let's say I have a C function:

```
Func(void* param);
```

Is there a way to know number of bytes of param content?

Comment: Not portably, no. All those standard library and user-defined functions you see passing a `size_t` length, in addition to a memory address in a pointer, are doing so for a reason. One of *many* related questions to this [can be seen **here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9390615/how-to-calculate-size-of-array-from-pointer-variable).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not possible. That's why almost all functions that takes pointers as arguments has an extra argument for size. It should be like this:

```
void func(void *param, int size);
```

Also note that it is up to the function to interpret the `size` argument. It can be number of bytes, number of elements or whatever.

The important thing here to remember is the only thing `param` is, is a memory address. Nothing more, nothing less.

Some functions doesn't utilize this. One example is `strcpy(char * dest, char * src)` that copies a string, but this function assumes two things. It assumes that `src` is a zero-terminated string. `strcpy` will read from `src` until it hits a `'\0'` character. Furthermore, it assumes that `dest` points at a memory location big enough to hold the string.

`sizeof(*param)` will not work. `param` is only a pointer to where the memory chunk starts. It would be the same as using `sizeof(void)`

Comment: @Hollyol you can't dereference a `void*`. Given your OP, what type is `param`? We don't know, the compiler doesn't know either. You have to cast it to its appropriate type before you can dereference it.

Comment: " Especially when it comes to void pointers, it can be a bit ambiguous" I'd argue the opposite. There's no reasonable unit of measure for the size of the object pointed to by a `void*` except bytes.

Comment: @JeremyP True, I removed that.

Answer (score 3):

For starters the type `void` is an incomplete type that is its size in bytes is indeterminate.

From the C Standard (6.2.5 Types)

> 19 The void type comprises an empty set of values; it is an incomplete
>   object type that cannot be completed.

However if you have a pointer of some other type as an argument of a function as for example

```
T *param
```

then in general case you again will be unable to determine the number of bytes occupied by the referenced actual data.

Pointers do not keep information whether they point to a single object or the first object of an array.

For example if you have a function declared like this

```
void f( const char *s );
```

then it can be called for example for these objects of different types

```
char c = 'A';
f( &c );
```

and

```
char s[] = "Hello";
f( s );
```

Of course you can get the number of bytes occupied by the element of an array or a single object referenced to by pointer as for example using expression

```
sizeof( *param )
```

But in case of the type `void *` you may not do even this though some compilers have their own language extensions that allow to apply the operator `sizeof` for the type void. In this case the returned value of the expression is usually equal to 1.

Answer (score 2):

No.  Without knowing what `param` is pointing to, you can't know what size it is.