# Insertion sort algorithm in C is not working

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, insertion-sort, function-definition

I am trying to sort an array of integers for finding the median of the same array. The code I am using sorts only the first two elements of the 10 element array. I have cross checked the swapping of variables in the loops, but everything seems okay.

```
void sort(int *arr) {
    //get the size of this array
    int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++) {
            if (arr[i] > arr[j]) {
                int temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***Application***

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int numbers[10];
    numbers[0] = 10;
    numbers[1] = 9;
    numbers[2] = 8;
    numbers[3] = 7;
    numbers[4] = 6;
    numbers[5] = 5;
    numbers[6] = 4;
    numbers[7] = 3;
    numbers[8] = 2;
    numbers[9] = 1;

    sort(numbers);
    //code sorts the element in the first and second index, the rest are unsorted please help

    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you call `sort(numbers)`, the array `numbers` "decays" into a pointer and determining the number of entries via `sizeof` will not work as intended. Instead, pass the size as second argument and calculate it in the same scope as the array definition.

Comment: Among the *many* related duplicates [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeof-a-pointer-pointing-to-an-array), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9390615/how-to-calculate-size-of-array-from-pointer-variable)

Answer (score 2):

The function parameter has a pointer type

```
void sort(int* arr){
```

Even if you will rewrite the function declaration like

```
void sort( int arr[10] ){
```

nevertheless the compiler will adjust the function parameter having the array type to pointer to the element type as it is written in your original function declaration

```
void sort(int* arr){
```

And in this call of the function

```
sort(numbers);
```

the array designator is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element. That is the call above in fact is the same as

```
sort( &numbers[0] );
```

So using the operator `sizeof` with a pointer expression yields the size of a pointer. That is this line

```
//get the size of this array
int size=sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
```

is equivalent to

```
//get the size of this array
int size=sizeof( int * )/sizeof( int );
```

and yields either 2 or 1 depending on the used system.

You need to declare the function like

```
void sort( int *arr, size_t n );
```

and pass to the function the number of elements in the array explicitly.

Bear in mind that in general the user can use the function for a dynamically allocated array.

Pay attention to that the used by you algorithm is not the insertion sort algorithm. It is the selection sort algorithm with redundant swaps.

A function that implements the insertion sort algorithm can look for example the following way as it is shown in the demonstration program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void insertion_sort( int a[], size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 1; i < n; i++ )
    {
        int current = a[i];
        size_t j = i;
        for ( ; j != 0 && current < a[j - 1]; j-- )
        {
            a[j] = a[j - 1];
        }

        if ( j != i ) a[j] = current;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int a[] = { 9,8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    insertion_sort( a, N );

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

The program output is

```
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

As for the function that implements the selection sort algorithm then without redundant swaps it can look the following way as it is shown in the next demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void selection_sort( int a[], size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        size_t min = i;

        for ( size_t j = i + 1; j < n; j++ )
        {
            if (a[j] < a[min]) min = j;
        }

        if ( min != i )
        {
            int tmp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[min];
            a[min] = tmp;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int a[] = { 9,8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    selection_sort( a, N );

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

The program output is the same as shown above

```
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: What if I don't know the number of elements in the pointer, how can I calculate ?

Comment: is there a way to cast the pointer to an array?

Comment: @PubliusFlaviusTiberius See you can never get the actual length of a pointer, if you didn't kept a track of the length

Comment: Okay, I will certainly check and see if there is somewhere I can get the length of the array

Comment: @PubliusFlaviusTiberius Read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/492410/17939455

Comment: @PubliusFlaviusTiberius Did you liked my answer??

Comment: @PubliusFlaviusTiberius You could determine the number of elements in an arbitrary array using a pointer only if the array has a sentinel value.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Yes like we do in `char *`, there `\0` is used to stop the counting of the length, but it will not return the length after `\0`

Answer (score 0):

This is because `int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);` will return **2**, because `sizeof(arr)` will give the **sizeof** a *pointer to int*, which in your case is *8 bytes* and then `sizeof(arr[0])` will give a **sizeof** `int` which in your case is *4 bytes*.

So,

```
8 / 4 = 2
```

**Fix:**

- Add another parameter for the length of the array.
- type-cast `numbers` to `(int *)` for `sort()` function
- Your `sort()` function does not implement insertion sort algorithm,  instead it is selection sort algorithm. [READ MORE](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/difference-between-insertion-sort-and-selection-sort)
- There's no need of `stdlib.h` header file in your code

Like this: [**`TRY IT ONLINE`**](https://godbolt.org/z/TcxM3scEd)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void sort(int *arr, size_t len)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < len; j++)
        {
            if (arr[i] > arr[j])
            {
                int temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

// using `const` keyword, because `arr` isn't modifying inside `print()` function
void print(const int *arr, size_t len){
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int numbers[10];
    numbers[0] = 10;
    numbers[1] = 9;
    numbers[2] = 8;
    numbers[3] = 7;
    numbers[4] = 6;
    numbers[5] = 5;
    numbers[6] = 4;
    numbers[7] = 3;
    numbers[8] = 2;
    numbers[9] = 1;

    size_t len = sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(numbers[0]);
    sort((int *)numbers, len);

    print(numbers, len);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but why do you cast `numbers` in `sort((int *)numbers, len)`? Using a different syntax in  `void sort(int *arr, size_t len)` and `void print(int arr[], size_t len)` is confusing if you do not teach the OP that these are exactly equivalent.  The OP needs to understand that arrays decay as pointers to their first element in most expression contexts.

Comment: So that it can change `numbers` inside a function, passing by reference also does the work, but `int *` cannot be converted to `int (*)[10]`

Comment: `int (*)[10]` is well beyond the OP's skill level, and frankly beyond most C programmers'.  You seem to have a very thorough understanding of the C language,  that is quite rare for a teenager :)  but defining the argument as `int *arr` or `int arr[]` is irrelevant to the constness of the argument or of its elements.

Comment: Thanks, @chqrlie you were in high school in 1974 

Comment: `print` should be defined as `void print(const int arr[], size_t len)` or `void print(const int *arr, size_t len)`. No difference.  The `[]` does convey the idea that `arr` indeed points to an array as opposed to a single `int`, but this is only a hint for the programmer who will read the code, the compiler does not care.

Comment: Yup, it can be even though `arr` isn't modifying inside `print()` function

Comment: @chqrlie Check out [this](https://github.com/Dark-CodeX/sstring/blob/main/sstring/sstring.h), which I have created previous year

Comment: yes, I looked at your github, but I have limited time right now.  I shall give you some feedback via another channel.

Comment: okay, thx @chqrlie