# sizeof() of 2 dimensional charecter array shows wrong o/p

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, sizeof

This programme shows only one output "Hiii" if the size of the words array is not passed from the main function.
If size is generated inside `disp` function shows
Size: 48
Size: 2
Hiii

If size is passed from  `main` function shows
Size: 48
Size: 48
Hiii
Hello
Hello There
Hello World

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void disp(char words[][12],int size)
{
 int i,j;
 char *p,*cp;
 p=words;
 size=sizeof(words);
 printf("Size %d\n",size);
 for(cp=p;cp<(p+size);cp+=12)
 {
  printf("%s",cp);
  printf("\n");
 }
}

void main()
{
 char words[][12]={"Hiii","Hello","Hello There","Hello World"};
 int size;
 clrscr();
 size=sizeof(words);
 printf("Size %d\n",size);
 disp(words,size);
 getch();
}
```

## Programme compiled in Borland Turbo C

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sizeof an array in the C programming language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975128/sizeof-an-array-in-the-c-programming-language)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, the syntax for passing an array is actually just a another way of saying you are passing a pointer.  For example:

```
void f(int a[])
```

is just another way of saying

```
void f(int *a)
```

It is a special syntax in the language, and it is meant to make the parameters more self documenting, but it can also be confusing in situations like what you are describing.

In your case, the declaration:

```
void disp(char words[][12],int size)
```

is actually saying

```
void disp(char (*words)[12],int size)
```

That is, words is a pointer to an array of 12 characters.  And the size of a pointer is two bytes in your case.

Answer (score 1):

The `sizeof` in `main()`gives the size of the array.
The `sizeof` in function `disp()`gives size of an pointer.

This is because when you try to pass an array to a function, it decays to an pointer to its first element.
The only way to get the size of an array inside the function is to pass it as an separate function argument, and that is the most usual way to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the difference between array and pointers better. Also that sizeof is computed at compile time, so sizeof words in main can get the actual size (your words array is a bidimentional char array, not a conventional array of char pointers, so each row has size 12 for a total of 48). Inside disp, there is no way ro know where the array ends and therefore no way to determine its size.  Read up k&r for better understanding