# sizeof operation on char array

Tags: c, sizeof

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find the sizeof(a pointer pointing to an array)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeofa-pointer-pointing-to-an-array)
>   [Sizeof an array in the C programming language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975128/sizeof-an-array-in-the-c-programming-language)

```
#include<stdio.h>

void doit(char x[10]){
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(x));
}

void main(void){
    char x[10];
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(x));
    doit(x);
}
```

** I don't know why my question is removed first time. **
Two outputs here are different. Apparently the first one knows x is an array and second one only knows it a ptr. My question is why compiler knows that in the first case it's an array instead of a ptr?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeofa-pointer-pointing-to-an-array

Comment: The name of an array evaluates to the address of the array *except* when passed to the `sizeof` or address-of (unary `*`) operators.

Comment: @cnicutar: Indeed, I just noticed that.  Deleting (rather than simply closing) duplicates doesn't strike me as a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am no compiler expert but during the compilation phase, the compiler performs something called *semantic analysis*. During this phase, type checking is done. `sizeof` is also a compile time operator ( barring VLArrays probably ) and during type checking the compiler determines that in `main`, `x` is an array and in `doit` function it is a pointer.

Its like, the compiler is the owner of the house and *hence it knows the type of its tenants*.

Read about the compilation process on [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler#Front_end)

Comment: The `doit` function parameter _is a pointer_. When an array is passed as a function parameter it always decays to a pointer.

Comment: @Blastfurnace I guess I haven't contradicted to the point you are making? May be the wording confuses you? Yes the function parameter is indeed a pointer as you cant pack arrays and send them

Comment: You kind of dance around the answer, but never really hit it.  The issue is that when an expression of array type appears in most contexts (such as in a function call), it is converted ("decays") to an expression of pointer type.  IOW, you have the cause and effect reversed.  The conversion doesn't happen because `doit` expects a pointer; rather, `doit` expects a pointer because the conversion happens.