# Determining Array Size in C

Tags: c, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sizeof an array in the C programming language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975128/sizeof-an-array-in-the-c-programming-language)

In my main function I have the following code:

```
struct student s1 = {"zack",0,0,82};
struct student s2 = {"bob",0,0,80};
struct student s3 = {"joe",0,0,97};
struct student s4 = {"bill",0,0,100};

struct student c[] = {s1,s2,s3,s4};

printf("%d\n\n", arrayLengths(c));
printf("%d\n\n", sizeof(c)/sizeof(c[0]));
```

where arrayLength is defined as:

```
int arrayLengths(struct student g[]) {
    return sizeof(g)/sizeof(g[0]);
}
```

With duplicate code though I am getting two different results. My console output is:

```
0
4
```

What gives? Why is this so and how can I put this in its own function?

Answer (score 2):

When an array is passed to a function it decays to a pointer, pointing to the first element in the array. So:

```
int arrayLengths(struct student g[]) {
    return sizeof(g)/sizeof(g[0]);
}
```

is actually:

```
int arrayLengths(struct student* g) {
    return sizeof(struct student*)/sizeof(struct student);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How would the code inside `arrayLengths` know how big the array is?

Answer (score 0):

Array passed to a function decays into a pointer. Pointer size is usually 4 bytes on a 32 bit system.

Whereas the size of the array in the main function will be equal to

```
sizeof(array element type) * (number of elements in the array)
```

This should explain the behavior which you are seeing.