# array's second integer

Tags: c++

This is a really simple program I'm writing here but came up to the problem.
well, the program fills the array[2000] from the file and then it should TYPE(cout) the array[i] which isn't equal to the second member of array. I am not sure how to point to the second member of array in program. here is the piece of program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
const int N=2000;

int main() {
    int* array;
    array = new int[N];

    for (int i=0; i<N; i++){
        ifstream ifs("reals.txt");
        ifs>>array[i];
    }

    for (int i=0; i<N; i++){
        if(array[i] != array[1])   /// is this right? is array[1] second member? 
            cout<<array[i]<<'\t';
        if((i+1)%13) cout<<endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

how will it be, if was I wanted to check for the second element from last element of array?

P.S. sorry for my English. if there is anything you can't understand, feel free to comment and I will try to explain. thanks in advance.

Comment: you should probably have just used `int array[2000];`

Comment: what, if anything, does the program output when you run it? Are there any errors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`array[1]` *is* the second member. Your problem is however that you are reopening the file every time in your loop:

```
for (int i=0; i<N; i++){
    ifstream ifs("reals.txt");
    ifs>>array[i];
}
```

you need to open the file before the loop:

```
ifstream ifs("reals.txt");
for (int i=0; i<N; i++){
    ifs>>array[i];
}
```

Comment: yeah, you're right. I will fix that.

by the way, if I want to make a function the to use in whatever, so I won't know the size of array. how would I point to the second element from the last one?

Comment: @GeoDrawkcab: The most straightforward way would bew to use std::array (or std::vector for a dynamic array), so the size is always known (myArray.size())

Comment: @GeoDrawkcab, see [this response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047239/how-can-i-know-legth-of-array-in-c/11047259#11047259) from a question earlier today.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i=0; i<N; i++){
    ifstream ifs("reals.txt");
    ifs>>array[i];
}
```

Should be

```
ifstream ifs("reals.txt");
for (int i=0; i<N; i++){        
    ifs>>array[i];
}
```

> if(array[i] != array[1])   /// is this right? is array[1] second
>   member?

The answer is yes.

> array = new int[N];

don't forget to

```
delete[] array;
```

If you want to access the prelast element, there is a drop-in replacement in the standard library for your array:

```
#include <vector>

int main(){
  std::vector<int> array(1000);
  array[998]= 42;
  int prelast= *(array.end()- 2); // end() is an iterator to one-past the last element
}
```

Comment: thanks and if, for example, I want to make a function the to use in whatever, so I won't know the size of array. how would I point to the second element from the last one? is there any kind of command similar to .size() in arrays?

Comment: in standard c++ we use containers for such things, I updated the answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is correct as arrays are `0` based. For example with an array of `5 elements` the last element would be `index 4 or array[4];`