# Why the array size is 1

Tags: c, arrays, sizeof

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sizeof an array in the C programming language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975128/sizeof-an-array-in-the-c-programming-language)

I'm trying to write a function that return 1s if a value is in the array. Here's the code:

```
int inArrayInt(int iVal, int iArray[])
{
    int i;
    int arrayL = sizeof(*iArray) / sizeof(int);
    int flag = 0;
    for(i=0; i < arrayL; i++)
    {
        if(iVal == iArray[i])
        {
            flag = 1;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

The problem is that `arrayL = sizeof(*iArray) / sizeof(int);` always evaluates to 1, even if array contains 20 elements. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a parameter `int iArray[]` is equivalent to `int *iArray`.

So when you do

```
int arrayL=sizeof(*iArray)/sizeof(int);
```

You are actually doing

```
int arrayL=sizeof(int)/sizeof(int);
```

Which is the same size.

You need to add a parameter with which you pass the size information.

```
int inArrayInt(int iVal, int iArray[], size_t numel){
  ...
  for(i=0;i<numel;i++){
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: He is actually doing `int arrayL=sizeof(int)/sizeof(int);`, there are two bugs in the code and you only address one.

Comment: @Lundin `sizeof(*iArray)` is not per se wrong. And applying the fix as a described will remove that error source.

Answer (score 7):

Because array decays to a pointer when you pass it into a function as an argument. And so the `sizeof(array)` will not give you the size of the array, but the size of the pointer.

You can either have the array size as an `extra argument`, or pass the array as a `reference` so that sizeof(array) will give you the correct size. (Detailed here: [What is array decaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying))

Comment: As a sidenote, the OP has commited another error by doing `sizeof(*iArray)`.

Answer (score 1):

What you pass to the function is a pointer to the array, with no way to know the size. The size of a pointer is the size of an int, hence the `1`.

You need to pass the size of the array along with it in the arguments of your function if you want to iterate on it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd add an extra parameter with the array size:

```
int inArrayInt(int iVal, int* iArray, int sizeOfArray)
{
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++)
    {
        if(iVal == iArray[i])
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }

   return 0;
}
```

Then call the function with the size you initiated the array with:

```
int myArray[100];  


if (inArrayInt(42, myArray, 100))
   //returned true
```