# C++ array size different result

Tags: c++, arrays, size

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sizeof an array in the C programming language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975128/sizeof-an-array-in-the-c-programming-language)

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    string a[] = {"some", "text"};

    void test(string a[])
    {
        int size_of_a = sizeof(a) /sizeof(a[0]);
        cout << size_of_a; 
    }
    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
        test(a); //gives 0
        int size_of_a = sizeof(a) /sizeof(a[0]);
        cout << size_of_a; //gives 2
        return 0;
    }
```

as u can see in the comment test(a) gives 0 instead of 2 as i would expect. Could someone explain why and how could i correct it? thanks

Comment: I also get `1` from `test(a)`

Comment: It would be very difficult to get 0, as `sizeof(a)` would need to be zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass an array to a function, it decays to a pointer to the first element of the array and so within your `test(string a[])` function

```
sizeof(a);
```

actually returns the size of a pointer and not the size of your array.

Comment: Thanks for the explonation. How should i correct it? Whats the best way to program this?

Comment: yay vectors! or C++11 std::array

Comment: @user1686999 As you are using C++ use a vector - they make lives so so much easier.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent array decaing to pointer, you can pass *reference* to array to the function. But it causes types of array of function formal argument and actual argument must coincide (including their sizes). So you need to use `template` to make your function work with an array of any size:

```
template <int N>
void foo(const string (&a)[N])
{
    int size_of_a = sizeof(a) /sizeof(a[0]);
    cout << size_of_a; 
}
```