# getting the length of an array after passing as a char*

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sizeof an array in the C programming language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975128/sizeof-an-array-in-the-c-programming-language)

I have code of the following form:

```
void arrLen(char* array){
    // print length
}

int main(){
    char bytes[16];
    arrLen(bytes);
}
```

What I need to do is get the length of the underlying array and print it out.  The issue is that the array MAY CONTAIN NULL CHARACTERS, and therefore `strlen` would not work.  is there any way to do this, or would I have to pass it as a `char[]` instead of a `char*`?

Comment: Well that's not really how arrays are handled in C. They are not actual objects that carry length information. If you have access to C++11, use std::array. If not, you must keep track of the memory length yourself at all times

Comment: why don't you just use `vector` or `array`?

Comment: void arrLen(char* array, int size)

Comment: @AK4749 Thank, but I do not have access to c++11, unfortunately.  Is there a boost module that could perform this?

Comment: @ewok indeed: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/array.html

Comment: Does the char[] end in a null character ('\o')?  You could use that to find the end of the array.

Comment: @RaySaltrelli well seeing as he says the char[] might be sprinkled with extra '\0's, I don't quite see how you can determine which is "the last" '\0'

Comment: @ewok: Also check if you have access to TR1, there is `std::tr1::array`. Boost also provides wrappers which automatically provide some version http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_tr1.html.

Comment: ^ Forgot about TR1 array. good call. Very few people don't have TR1 now

Comment: @AK4749 Ah, I didn't notice that part of the OP. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C style arrays do not carry length information with them.

You have several solutions avaliable :

pass the size of your array to your function :

```
void arrLen(char* array, std::size_t size)
```

use [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) if you have access to C++ 11 (or TR1 as mentionned in comments)

```
 std::array<char, 16> bytes;
```

If you don't have access to std::array, you can use [boost::array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/array.html). They are roughly equivalent to the standard one.

Regarding your comment

> would I have to pass it as a char[] instead of a char*?

Arrays are always passed to functions as pointers, so `void arrLen(char* array)` and `void arrLen(char[] array)` are equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

> or would I have to pass it as a char[] instead of a char*?

Changing the declaration of `arrLen()` to take a parameter of type `char[]` instead of `char*` would have no effect, as in this scenario they are equivalent.

A possible solution would be to use a `template` function:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, int N>
void array_size(T (&a)[N])
{
    std::cout << N << "\n";
}
int main()
{
    array_size("hello");
    char bytes[16];
    array_size(bytes);
    return 0;
}
```

See http://ideone.com/l7GxDp for demo.

Alternatives to using an array:

- `std::string`; these can contain NULL characters:

  ```
      std::string s("hello\0world", 11);
  ```
- [`std::vector<char>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)
- [`boost::array<char, 16>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/array.html) (available as [`std::array<char,16>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) in C++11, or [`std::tr1::array`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983093.aspx) in most every C++ compiler on the market)

Comment: Considering that `std::array` is standard as of C++11, I'd prefer seeing a reference to that as well when mentioning boost::array.

Comment: @Agentlien, I know that but in a comment to the question the OP states that C++11 is not available.

Comment: Sure, but I'd still add a comment, possibly within parentheses. As such: *boost::array<char,16> (available as std::array<char,16> in C++11* That would help people who come to this question later and do not have that restriction.

Answer (score 2):

In the traditional way (C) one has to pass the size as an attribute of the function

```
void arrLen(char* array, int maxSize){
    // print length
}

int main(){
    char bytes[16];
    arrLen(bytes, 16);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

arrays in C/C++ aren't handled that way per say, you have to manually keep track of the length yourself.. change your function to something like `void arrLen(char * array, int size)` and specify the size whenever you call the function.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a C++11, may I suggest that you use [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), it keeps track of it size.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `char[]` and `char*` parameter types are equivalent.

You have two options:

Pass the length along with the pointer like one would in  C:

```
void arrLen(char* array, size_t length)
```

or use a template:

```
template<size_t sz>
void arrLen(char (&array)[sz])
```