# C++11 std::begin doesn't work with int[] passed into template function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I've got an issue: no matching function for call to ‘begin(int*&)’
The only hint I've found on it is that compiler might not know the size of array at compile time, but I believe that's not my case.
Here is what I've got:

```
template <typename T>
void heapSort(T array[]) {
  size_t length = std::end(array) -  std::begin(array);
  if (length == 0) {
    return;
  }
  Heap<T> heap(array);
  for (size_t i = length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    array[i] = heap.pop();
  }
}

int main() {      
  int array[] = {9, 8, 10, 99, 100, 0};
  for (auto i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
    std::cout << array[i] << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
  heapSort(array);
  for (auto i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
    std::cout << array[i] << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

What's the problem? How can I solve it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sizeof an array in the C programming language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975128/sizeof-an-array-in-the-c-programming-language)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
void heapSort(T array[]);
```

is just alternative syntax for

```
void heapSort(T* array);
```

You can't pass an array by value, so you need to take it by reference (and possibly let the compiler deduce its size):

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
void heapSort(T (&array)[N]);
```

Note that this way you'll get a different instantiation for each array of distinct size. It might lead to some code bloat if you've got a large number of arrays. I'd consider using a `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Instead of a `vector` or an array, the best thing would be to take first and last iterators... `template<class RandomIt> void heapSort(RandomIt first, RandomIt last)` (note the template argument is named for the [standard iterator template policy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator) it is required to be)

Answer (score 2):

Like *jrok* said, `T array[]` is just a synonym for a pointer `T* array` which looses any information about the actual array type.

If you really want to use a compile time array, it's actually

```
template<typename T,std::size_t N> void heapSort(T (&array)[N])
```

(And that's in the end what `std::begin` and `std::end` do, too.)

Answer (score 2):

The other problem is that `size_t` is always non-negative, so your loop `for (size_t i = length - 1; i >= 0; --i)` will never terminate. Try replacing with:

```
for (size_t i = length; i > 0; --i) {
  array[i - 1] = heap.pop();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `Heap` is usable with `std::begin/end`?

Comment: There's no way I could be - all we can tell from the code given is that `Heap` is some kind of container template class. I am however sure that it _should_ have a `begin()` and `end()`. (Well, we can suppose that it's a sorted container as well ;)

Comment: Given that the name is `Heap`, it's very likely not sorted and implements a heap, so a direct element-by-element copy would fail to give a proper sort order.

Comment: Heap is a class I've implemented. It may be a good idea to have begin() and end() methods, thanks! The thing is I wanted to implement my own class heap and heapSort() just for testing purposes.