# Sizeof List and traversal

Tags: c

I have this array in main.

```
int main()
{
    int list[] = {1,2,3};

    print_list(list);
}
```

According to the compiler warning the list is `NULL` terminated.

When I try to print the list I will print an extra element because sizeof(list) seems to be +1.

```
void print_list(const int *list)
{ 
    int i;
    for(i=0; i < sizeof(list); i++)
        printf(list[i]);
}
```

Should I run the for loop with `sizeof(list) - 1` for any case that looks like this?
Or should I check inside the loop for `if(list[i] == NULL`?

If my function was not making a pointer out of the list I could use: `sizeof(list)/sizeof(list[0])`

**The function is turning the array into a pointer. So how can I get the accurate size?**

It is true my question is very simple and trivial to some. I do believe I have shown enough effort though, please help.

[EDIT]
[Why isn't the size of an array parameter the same as within main?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975128/sizeof-an-array-in-the-c-programming-language) 
That is what I know already, it still doesn't answer my question so not a duplicate.

Comment: In function `print_list()`, `list` is just a pointer. So you get the sizeof the pointer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sizeof an array in the C programming language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975128/sizeof-an-array-in-the-c-programming-language)

Comment: Yeah I am aware of what is going on with the pointer. So how do I get the accurate size?

Comment: Note that even if it were an array, your code would be wrong. `sizeof list` would be 12 on most machines, not 3. You have to do `sizeof array  / sizeof *array` to get the number of elements in an array (unless it's an array of `char`).

Comment: The answer to your question is simple: you **can't**. You have to pass the size as a parameter, or put an end marker in the array.

Comment: The comment "The function is turning the array into a pointer" is a red flag.  C arrays *are* pointers into memory, there is nothing to turn it into.  "list" is just a name, not a C structure, so the function is not "making a pointer out of the list" - the variable "list" was always just a pointer, except in how your code used it.  There is no way to get the size of the entire array from the pointer to the array.

Comment: @BlueMoon The other question is specifically a 'why' question, whereas this is a 'how' question.

Comment: @mydoghasworms exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sizeof` returns the size in bytes of its parameter. `sizeof(int*)` will return, in most architectures, 4. It is impossible to get the size of the array using a pointer. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeofa-pointer-pointing-to-an-array)

Use this code:

main:

```
int main()
{
    int list[] = {1,2,3};

    print_list(list, sizeof(list) / sizeof(int));
}
```

print_list:

```
void print_list(const int *list, int size)
{ 
    int i;
    for(i=0; i < size; i++)
        printf(list[i]);
}
```

Comment: I personally like `#define LENGTHOF(a) (sizeof(a) / sizeof((a)[0]))` as it makes the rest of the code more legible when it is used frequently.  [Ideone example](http://ideone.com/YXkGGV)

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof list` reports the size of the variable `list`, which is a `const int *`, in modern computers it will probably be something like 4 or 8.

When you pass the array as a parameter to a function, it isn't an array anymore, the function receives a pointer.

In [this link](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryparmsize.html) you can find the answer to your question. I recommend you to read [this whole page](http://c-faq.com/~scs/cgi-bin/faqcat.cgi?sec=aryptr) (it is short), just to learn the difference between pointers and arrays.

Comment: Might be 16 or 32 in the future?!

Comment: Probably not, unless we ever design computers that can use the Internet as part of their main memory. But never say never -- Bill Gates supposedly opined that 640Kb would be enough for personal computers (although he claims he never said this, and no citation can be found).