# sizeof operation on a 2D array

Tags: c, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

If I define a 2D array as:

```
char *tablechar[][2] = {
      {"0",  "Innova"},
      {"2",  "Brio"  },
      {"3",  "Alto"  },
      {"4",  "Bolero"},
      {"5",  "Swift" }
};
```

and code in the same file as:

```
printf("Value = %d\n",sizeof(tablechar));
printf("Value = %d\n",sizeof(tablechar[0]));
printf("Num of rows = %d\n",sizeof(tablechar)/sizeof(tablechar[0]));
```

Output is as expected:

```
Value = 40
Value = 8
Num of rows = 5
```

Now, I pass this 2D matrix in a function whose defination is:

```
void printstuff(char *tab[][2])
{
   printf("Value = %d\n",sizeof(tab));
   printf("Value = %d\n",sizeof(tab[0]));
   printf("Num of rows = %d\n",sizeof(tab)/sizeof(tab[0]));
}
```

I get the following output:

```
Value = 4
Value = 8
Num of rows = 0
```

with a compiler warning in the above function as:

[image: compiler_warning]

Why is it so that the value of sizeof(tab) and sizeof(tablechar) different?

Comment: 4 is size of pointer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the 'sizeof'(a pointer pointing to an array)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeofa-pointer-pointing-to-an-array)

Comment: [Sizeof an array in the C programming language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975128/sizeof-an-array-in-the-c-programming-language?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tablechar` is an actual array, but the argument `tab` will be treated as a pointer to elements of array having the specified type, so `sizeof(tab)` will be size of pointers while `sizeof(tablechar)` will be size of the array.

By the way, passing data having wrong type to `printf()` invokes *undefined behavior*. You will have to use `%zu` instead of `%d` for printing `size_t`, to which the `sizeof` operator will evaluated.

Comment: Is there any way that I can take a 2D array formal parameter in a function that can be deciphered as an array itself, not a pointer?

Answer (score 2):

`tablechar` is an array of arrays of `char` pointers while the function parameter `tab` is a pointer to an array of 2 `char` pointers.

```
void printstuff(char *tab[][2])
```

is equivalent to

```
void printstuff(char *(*tab)[2])
```

`sizeof(tab)` will give the size of pointer not the array `tablechar`. In C, there is way to pass an array to a function. When you pass an array to a function then as per C rule array decay to pointer to its first element.
Always remember that **arrays are not pointers**.

Answer (score 1):

for:

```
char *tablechar[][2] = {
      {"0",  "Innova"},
      {"2",  "Brio"  },
      {"3",  "Alto"  },
      {"4",  "Bolero"},
      {"5",  "Swift" }
};
```

The type of `tablechar` is a array which have `five` elements, the type of each element is `char* [2]`. So `sizeof(tablechar) = 5 * sizeof(char* [2]) = 5 * 8 = 5 * 4 * 2`.

The type if `tablechar[0]` is `char* [2]`, so `sizeof(tablechar[0]) = sizeof(char*) * 2 = 4 * 2 = 8`.

for

```
void printstuff(char *tab[][2])
{
   printf("Value = %d\n",sizeof(tab));
   printf("Value = %d\n",sizeof(tab[0]));
   printf("Num of rows = %d\n",sizeof(tab)/sizeof(tab[0]));
}
```

The type of `tab` is `char**`, so `sizeof(tab) = 4`.
The type of `tab[0]` is `char* [2]`, so `sizeof(tab[0]) = 8`.