# How to initialize an array in private class without using a constant array size?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a header and .cpp file. I am having difficulty initializing the array. The problem is that I can't specify the array size. The size depends on the number of elements the user inputs. When I make a new dynamicArray, I believe I have to use the "new" like dynamicArray = new string[sizeof(array)] (because I have to delete the memory later according to the assignment) but when I run it through Linux, it says that it cannot appear in a constant - expression.

I'm still a little unfamiliar with C++. Any feedback is appreciated.

What the error looks like:

[image]

I also had issues with the header redefinition and I think the #pragma once helped.
I know #include "stdafx.h" is bad for linux. I remove it every time I run it on linux.

DynamaicStringArray.cpp

```
// DynamicStringArray.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "DynamicStringArray.h"
#include "Assignment9Test_V1.cpp"

// copy constructor that copies the array
DynamicStringArray::DynamicStringArray(string array[]) {
    // string *dynamicArray = new string[sizeof(array)]; // without pointer, error with conversion between types
    dynamicArray = new string[sizeof(array)];

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(array); i++) {
        dynamicArray[i] = array[i];
    }
}

// default constructor
DynamicStringArray::DynamicStringArray() {
    size = 0;

    dynamicArray = NULL;
    // dynamicArray = new string[size];
}

// frees up dynamic array memory
void DynamicStringArray::destructor(string array[]) {
    delete[] array;
    array = NULL;
}

// return number of entries in array
int DynamicStringArray::getSize() {
    return size;
}

// creates a new dynamic array one element larger than dynamicArray
// copies all elements of dynamicArray to new array and
// add new string to end of new array
// increment size
// delete old dynamicArray
// set new array as dynamicArray
void DynamicStringArray::addEntry(string newString) {
    string *newArray;
    newArray = new string[size + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        newArray[i] == dynamicArray[i];
    }

    int endIndex = sizeof(newArray);
    newArray[endIndex] = newString;

    destructor(dynamicArray);
    dynamicArray = newArray;
}

// searches for dynamicArray for specific string,
// if string not found, return false
// if string is found, create new one size smaller dynamic array
// than dynamicArray
// copy elements of old dynamicArray to new array without the string
// delete old dynamicArray
// decrement size
// return true
bool DynamicStringArray::deleteEntry(string deleteMe) {
    string *newArray;
    newArray = new string[size - 1];

    bool isFound = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (dynamicArray[i] == deleteMe) {
            i++;
            isFound = true;
        }
        else if (dynamicArray[i] != deleteMe) {
            newArray[i] == dynamicArray[i];
        }
    }

    if (isFound) {
        return true;
        destructor(dynamicArray);

        dynamicArray = newArray;
    }
    else if (!isFound) {
        return false;
    }
}

// returns the string at that index
string DynamicStringArray::getEntry(int findMe) {
    return dynamicArray[findMe];
}
```

DynamicStringArray.h

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class DynamicStringArray {
public:
    DynamicStringArray();

    DynamicStringArray(string array[]);

    // overloading the assignment operator

    void destructor(string array[]);
    int getSize();
    void addEntry(string);
    bool deleteEntry(string);
    string getEntry(int);

private:
    int size; // holds number of entries in the array
    string *dynamicArray; // references a dynamic array of type string
};
```

Comment: Use a std::vector.

Comment: `sizeof` is a compile-time constant. The size of the array must be known at compile time. Which is obviously not the case here, and why the whole thing goes down in flaming wreckage.

Comment: You should **listen more carefully your teacher** during course!

Comment: `void DynamicStringArray::destructor(` -- In C++, we have [destructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor)

Comment: When `array[]` is a parameter, `sizeof(array)` doesn't even tell you how many elements there are in the array. [Why isn't the size of an array parameter the same as within main?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975128/why-isnt-the-size-of-an-array-parameter-the-same-as-within-main) And in the `addEntry` this code `newArray[i] == dynamicArray[i];` will compare the elements instead of copying them.

Comment: I can't use vectors. We weren't taught that in class. I had size initially where sizeof was but that still didn't work. For destructor, I have to define my own function instead of a function that is already provided. And thanks @BoPersson I didn't notice that one.

Comment: @MainaAoita: There are a LOT of problems with your code.  Lack of a proper destructor. Mismanaging your `size` variable.  Not copying strings correctly. Not following the [Rule of Three](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). To name a few...

Comment: @RemyLebeau I haven't heard of Rule of Three before. I'll look into it.

Comment: @MainaAoita *I have to define my own function instead of a function that is already provided*  -- This is one of the most bizarre things I've ever heard of.  A destructor is already provided for you by C++.  The issue is that you need to customize it to delete the memory instead of the default behavior.  Who is teaching you C++?

Comment: @Maina - The sad thing is that once you have learned about `std::vector` you will never do things like this again. To me it looks a bit like you are taught how to ride a unicycle first, before being shown the "advanced" two wheel bike.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your instinct to use `new` (specifically, `new[]` and `delete[]`) to solve this issue is correct.  You must dynamically allocate the array at runtime since you don't know the number of elements at compile-time.  However, you are not using `new[]`/`delete[]` correctly, which is why you are getting errors (amongst many other problems with your code).

Try something more like this instead:

DynamicStringArray.h

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

class DynamicStringArray {
public:
    DynamicStringArray();
    DynamicStringArray(const std::string *array, int arraySize);
    DynamicStringArray(const DynamicStringArray &array);
    ~DynamicStringArray();

    DynamicStringArray& operator=(const DynamicStringArray &array);

    int getSize() const;
    void addEntry(const std::string &newString);
    bool deleteEntry(const std::string &deleteMe);
    std::string getEntry(int findMe) const;

private:
    int size; // holds number of entries in the array
    string *dynamicArray; // references a dynamic array of type string
};
```

DynamicStringArray.cpp

```
// DynamicStringArray.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "DynamicStringArray.h"

// default constructor
DynamicStringArray::DynamicStringArray() {
    size = 0;
    dynamicArray = NULL;
}

// constructor that copies an array
DynamicStringArray::DynamicStringArray(const std::string *array, int arraySize) {
    size = arraySize;
    dynamicArray = new std::string[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        dynamicArray[i] = array[i];
    }
}

// copy constructor that copies the array
DynamicStringArray::DynamicStringArray(const DynamicStringArray &array) {
    size = array.size;
    dynamicArray = new std::string[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        dynamicArray[i] = array.dynamicArray[i];
    }
}

// frees up dynamic array memory
DynamicStringArray::~DynamicStringArray() {
    delete[] array;
}

// copy assignment operator that copies the array
DynamicStringArray& DynamicStringArray::operator=(const DynamicStringArray &array) {
    if (&array != this) {
        DynamicStringArray copied(array);
        std::string *temp = copied.dynamicArray;
        copied.dynamicArray = dynamicArray;
        dynamicArray = temp;
        size = array.size;
    }
    return *this;
}

// return number of entries in array
int DynamicStringArray::getSize() const {
    return size;
}

// creates a new dynamic array one element larger than dynamicArray
// copies all elements of dynamicArray to new array and
// add new string to end of new array
// increment size
// delete old dynamicArray
// set new array as dynamicArray
void DynamicStringArray::addEntry(const std::string &newString) {
    std::string *newArray = new std::string[size + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        newArray[i] = dynamicArray[i];
    }
    newArray[size] = newString;
    delete[] dynamicArray;
    dynamicArray = newArray;
    ++size;
}

// searches the dynamic array for a specific string,
// if string not found, return false
// if string is found, create new array one size smaller than dynamicArray
// copy elements of old dynamicArray to new array without the string
// delete old dynamicArray and replace with new array
// decrement size
// return true
bool DynamicStringArray::deleteEntry(const string &deleteMe) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (dynamicArray[i] == deleteMe) {
            std::string *newArray = new std::string[size - 1];
            for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
                newArray[j] = dynamicArray[j];
            }
            for (int j = i+1; j < size; ++j) {
                newArray[j-1] = dynamicArray[j];
            }
            delete[] dynamicArray;
            dynamicArray = newArray;
            --size;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// returns the string at that index
std::string DynamicStringArray::getEntry(int findMe) const {
    return dynamicArray[findMe];
}
```

That being said, using a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is the preferred solution.  It is a dynamic-sized array that wraps `new[]`/`delete[]` for you.  It is simpler and safer to use than using `new[]`/`delete[]` directly, eg:

DynamicStringArray.h

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class DynamicStringArray {
public:
    DynamicStringArray();
    DynamicStringArray(const std::string *array, int arraySize);

    int getSize() const;
    void addEntry(const std::string &newString);
    bool deleteEntry(const std::string &deleteMe);
    std::string getEntry(int findMe) const;

private:
    std::vector<std::string> dynamicArray; // dynamic array of type string
};
```

DynamicStringArray.cpp

```
// DynamicStringArray.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "DynamicStringArray.h"
#include <algorithm>

// default constructor
DynamicStringArray::DynamicStringArray() {
}

// copy constructor that copies the array
DynamicStringArray::DynamicStringArray(const std::string *array, int arraySize) :
    dynamicArray(array, array + arraySize) {
}

// return number of entries in array
int DynamicStringArray::getSize() const {
    return dynamicArray.size();
}

// appends a new element to the end of the dynamic array
void DynamicStringArray::addEntry(const std::string &newString) {
    dynamicArray.push_back(newString);
}

// searches the dynamic array for a specific string,
// if string not found, return false
// if string is found, remove it and return true
bool DynamicStringArray::deleteEntry(const std::string &deleteMe) {
    std::vector<std::string>::iterator iter = std::find(dynamicArray.begin(), dynamicArray.end(), deleteMe);
    if (iter != dynamicArray.end())
    {
        dynamicArray.erase(iter);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// returns the string at that index
std::string DynamicStringArray::getEntry(int findMe) const {
    return dynamicArray[findMe];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your help