# stdlib.h qsort() on char array crashes in c

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int cmpfunc(const void *a, const void *b) {
   const char *ia = (const char*)a;
   const char *ib = (const char*)b;
   return *ia - *ib;
}

int is_permutation(char *s1, char *s2){
    int i, n1, n2;


    n1 = sizeof(s1)/sizeof(s1[0]);
    n2 = sizeof(s2)/sizeof(s2[0]);


    if(n1 != n2){
        return 0;
    }


    qsort(s1, n1, sizeof(s1), cmpfunc);
    qsort(s2, n2, sizeof(s2), cmpfunc);

    for (i = 0; i < n1;  i++)
       if (s1[i] != s2[i])
         return 0;

    return 1;
}

int main(){
    char s1[5] = "check";
    char s2[5] = "check";

    printf("%d", is_permutation(s1,s2));

    return 0;
}
```

It just crashes with no compiler errors. I've checked and the qsort crashes the program, everything else seems to work appropriately. Any help?

I compile with "gcc -g -ansi -pedantic -Wall prog.c -o prog"

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `sizeof(<some pointer>)` in C returns the size of the pointer, not what it points to (here, a string).

Comment: What will be the `sizeof(s1)` ?

Comment: `n1 = sizeof(s1)/sizeof(s1[0]);` - inside your function this is nonsensical.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why isn't the size of an array parameter the same as within main?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975128/why-isnt-the-size-of-an-array-parameter-the-same-as-within-main)

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof(s1)` &c. is **not** a function of the number of elements in the array. This is because `s1` has *decayed* to a pointer type.

`strlen` can be used to get the length of a string, but you'd need to write

```
char s1[6] = "check";
```

or better still,

```
char s1[] = "check";
```

to allow space for the NUL-terminator.

Answer (score 0):

*I've checked and the qsort crashes the program, everything else seems to work appropriately. ?* No, have a run in debugger ? Try compiling with `-g` option and run `gdb` and do `bt`.

The problematic statement are

```
n1 = sizeof(s1)/sizeof(s1[0]); /* it will results in 4/1 that is 4 */
n2 = sizeof(s2)/sizeof(s2[0]);
```

Instead rotate loop inside `s1` and find the length or use `strlen()` to find the length of `s1` and `s2` as

```
for(n1 = 0;s1[n1]!='\0'; n1++); /* dummy loop, at the end of loop, n1 will be length of s1 */
for(n2 = 0;s2[n2]!='\0'; n2++);
```

And

```
qsort(s1, n1, sizeof(s1[0]), cmpfunc);
qsort(s2, n2, sizeof(s2[0]), cmpfunc);
```

Here is the sample `is_permutation()` function

```
int is_permutation(char *s1, char *s2){
        int i, n1, n2;
        for(n1 = 0;s1[n1]!='\0'; n1++); /* dummy loop, at the end of loop, n1 will be length of s1 */
        for(n2 = 0;s2[n2]!='\0'; n2++);

        if(n1 != n2){
                return 0;
        }
        qsort(s1, n1, sizeof(s1[0]), cmpfunc);
        qsort(s2, n2, sizeof(s2[0]), cmpfunc);

        for (i = 0; i < n1;  i++)
                if (s1[i] != s2[i])
                        return 0;

        return 1;
}
```

Most importantly `char s1[5]="check"` doesn't have space for `\0` char. So either make `char s1[6]` or `char s1[]= "check"`

Comment: `strlen` will be UB since there's no space for the NUL terminator in the strings.

Comment: yes agree @Bathsheba . for that I suggested `n1+1` and `n2+1`. Is it correct ?

Comment: No it isn't: `n1 = strlen(s1);` is still UB.

Comment: Ok. I modified @Bathsheba

Comment: Did you reimplement `strlen` due to the issue Bathsheba mentioned? If so, this won't help as it does the same thing as `strlen`. It's the input strings that need to be fixed.

Comment: Or sizeof(s1[0]) will be fine. @Persixty

Comment: @achal Better still... Also you want `qsort(s1, n1, sizeof(s1[0]), cmpfunc);`. The elements of the array (i.e. string) are single characters. Of course `sizeof(s1[0])==1` is defined but it's code to make the meaning clear.

Comment: I don't think you've noticed that char `s1[5]="check";` may lose the NUL terminator. There are 5 characters in `"check"` but 6 required to include the terminator. That's what Bathsheba is hinting at.

Comment: Yes I changed @Persixty changed. Thanks.