# Sizeof on array function parameter will return size of 'double *' instead of 'double []'

Tags: objective-c, arrays

This is my code:

```
double findMax(double arr[]){
    double max = arr[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(arr); i++) {
        if (arr[i] > max) {
            max = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

I don't know how to do in Objective-C. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why isn't the size of an array parameter the same as within main?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975128/why-isnt-the-size-of-an-array-parameter-the-same-as-within-main)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not so keen to work with C-arrays, and also you can afford to map your data into an `NSArray`, plus you don't need to worry about performance at all... I'd recommend to do such thing in ObjC:

```
- (NSNumber *)maxIn:(NSArray<NSNumber *> *)array {
    return [array valueForKeyPath:@"@max.doubleValue"];
}
```