# Why can't I return a int[] from my C function

Tags: c, pointers

I somehow can not return a int[] from my function I wrote in the code below. Can anybody explain why I am doing it wrong, instead of only posting a code solution .

Why can't I square all values and set arr = square_all(arr)?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print(int arr[])
{
    for(int i = 0; i <= sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int); i++)
    {
        printf("%i", arr[i]);
    }
}

int* square_all(int arr[])
{
    for(int i = 0; i <= sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int); i++)
    {
        arr[i] = arr[i] * arr[i];
    }

    return arr;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3};
    print(arr);
    arr = square_all(arr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Answer (score 4):

The problem isn't the returning, but rather the *assignment* to `arr` in the `main` function.

You can't assign to an array, only to its individual elements. You can also copy to an array.

However, in this case there's no need for an assignment (or a copy), since you modify the array *in-place*. So all you really need is:

```
square_all(arr);  // No assignment
```

---

A larger problem is your use of `sizeof` in the functions. Because you don't pass an array to the functions, you pass a *pointer*. And the size of a pointer is the size of a pointer is the size of the actual pointer itself and not what it might point to.

See [Why isn't the size of an array parameter the same as within main?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975128/why-isnt-the-size-of-an-array-parameter-the-same-as-within-main)

Furthermore, since array indexes are zero-based, an array of `X` elements will have indexes from `0` to `X - 1`, inclusive. That means a loop-condition like `i <= X` will include `X` as an index, and that's out of bounds. Use `i < X` as a loop condition instead.

My guess is that you misunderstood how arrays are passed to functions, that arrays are copied for the function calls, which they are not. A function argument declaration like `int arr[]` is actually translated by the compiler as `int *arr`. And when you call the function, you only pass a pointer to its first element (e.g. `print(arr)` is really equal to `print(&arr[0])`).