# output,sum and product of array is wrong

Tags: c++

im learning c++ and i made a menu driven program where it creates ,display , finds the sum and the product of an array.
when i try to display, find the sum and product of the array ,the program changes the first element of the array and then does the display, sum and product

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void input(int a[],int& n){
    for (int i = 0;i <= n-1 ; i++){
        int val;
        cout << "Enter value: ";
        cin >> val;
        a[i] = val;
    }
    return;
}

void display(int a[],int& n){
    cout << "Values present are: ";
    for (int i = 0;i<=n-1;i++) cout << a[i] << " ";
}

void sum(int a[],int& n){
    int sum = 0;;
    for (int i = 0;i<= n-1;i++){
        sum += a[i];
    }
    cout << "SUM = " << sum;
}


void product(int a[],int& n){
    int product = 1;
    for (int i = 0;i<= n-1;i++){
        product *= a[i];
    }
    cout << "PRODUCT = " << product;
}


int main(){
    while (true){
        
        int ch ;
        cout << "\n1.Create list \n2.Display values \n3.Find Sum \n4.Find product \n5.EXIT"<<endl;
        cout << "Enter choice: ";
        cin >> ch;
        int lst[] = {};
        int n;
        if (ch == 1) {
            cout << "Enter number of values to be added: ";
            cin >> n;
            input(lst,n);
        }
        else if (ch == 2) display(lst,n);
        else if (ch == 3) sum(lst,n);
        else if (ch == 4) product(lst,n);
        else if (ch == 5) break;
        else cout << "INVALID CHOICE";
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgNWj.png)

i tried to remove the arguments of the functions and instead used sizeof(arr) but it did not work

Comment: `int lst[] = {};` whats the size of this array? You should probably use a [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead. This gives me the following error with msvc: *`error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0`*.

Comment: An array does not grow when you write past the end of it.  Instead, you get Undefined Behavior.

Comment: The conventional loop limit is `i < n`, not `i<= n-1`. Get used to the convention, it is a good one.

Comment: For `sizeof(arr)` see [Why isn't the size of an array parameter the same as within main?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975128/why-isnt-the-size-of-an-array-parameter-the-same-as-within-main) Easily solved by using a `std::vector`, which knows its own size.

Comment: `sizeof(arr)` also doesn't tell you how many elements `arr` has.  It tells you how many **bytes** have been allocated for the object.

Comment: You should get yourself a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

When using "modern C++" or just C++, prefer to use std::array over plain C arrays, next, you are trying to change the size of the array at run time, so you cannot use an array, you should use a vector(std::vector) which works just like an array, but supports adding elements at run time.

Also there is no need to pass `int& n` as a reference, it is a trivially copyable type. This way the prototype of your product function would be: `void product(std::vector<int>& data,int n)`, note the use of the reference when passing the vector to avoid copying it

Comment: your usage of the term "trivially copyable" is off. "Trivially copyable" means that objects can be copied by merely copying their bytes. It has no relation to the cost of that copy and is irrelevant for deciding to pass a reference vs making a copy