# Unable to understand array as pointers in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am trying to get the size of the array initialized in two different ways

The output for the below code as expected is 10.

```
    int a[10];
    cout<<sizeof(a)/sizeof(int); // 10
```

But for the below code the output is 1. Why??

```
    int* a = new int[10];
    cout<<sizeof(a)/sizeof(int); // 1
```

I was experimenting this while learning the concept "arrays as pointer". I expected to get the size of a in the second case as 10 too.

Comment: I don't know what you think the concept "arrays as pointer" means. Arrays are not pointers. Arrays can _decay into_ pointers under some circumstances. `sizeof(a)` in your first code snippet is not one of those circumstances.

Comment: `int* a` is a pointer and has the size of a pointer.  While it can point to an array, it does not know the size of the array that it may be pointing at.

Comment: Essentially answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975128/why-isnt-the-size-of-an-array-parameter-the-same-as-within-main

Comment: Consider using `std::array` instead of C-style arrays. Then you can simply call the `.size()` member function.

Comment: The question as asked is a duplicate as I've marked it. However, for practical purposes @JesperJuhl has the right idea: use `std::array` for statically known arrays, and `std::vector` for dynamically sized arrays, and you don't need to mess around with the weird behavior of language-level arrays.

Comment: If you had used the modern and clear `std::size(a)` instead of the 50-year-old `sizeof(a)/sizeof(int)`, the compiler would have identified your mistake to you.

Comment: `new` is an advanced C++ feature, and should not be used by beginners — use `std::make_unique` instead.  C-style arrays are an advanced C++ feature, and should not be used by beginners — use `std::vector` instead.  If you avoid those two things, does that make your problems go away?

Comment: so i just learnt about the std::vector. and it seems much more easier to understand. thanx @Eljay

Answer (score 1):

In the second case, `int* a` is a variable that points to the memory address of `a[]`, that means it occupies just the space of a regular int, so you have 8bytes/8bytes or whatever.

`int* a` should look like a string of text or something. While it's not completely accurate, I hope it explains the idea. ex: 0x00000001

If you meant array of pointers, then you should make an array of pointers instead a pointer to an array